# biblatex : which style for a footnote once then nothing?

Tags: biblatex, footnotes, citing

Ok sorry for this not so clear title. I'm having trouble to express & find what seems so simple :s

I'm biblatex and I would like to know which citation style/bibliographical style and/or option I should use to have my bibliography ordered this way. I put you an example of a thesis from my lab here http://historique.icsn.cnrs-gif.fr/IMG/pdf/Extraction-metabolites-epongesFR2010.pdf

So, in a nutshell:

- exponent numbers
- footnote reference for the first time the ref is cited
- later on when it is again cited nothing happens no op cit no ibid
- ref numbers identical in the text, the footnote and the final bibliography
- all same data (the exponent, the footnote and the ref in the final bibliography linked via hyperref)
- citation style as Authors (Last name then First Name initials) Journal, year in bold, vol, pages.

Seems the most current setting globally for me ... but maybe it isn't. 
I passed the whole day in a manner to figure that. Nothing until know, thus I have learned a lot.

Comment: Could you precise something? When you say that the second time something is cited nothing happens (no op cit, no ibid), do you mean that you want a complete citation everytime, or that you just want the abbreviation? The rest is easy (same data in footnote and bibliography, ref numbers identicals...).

Comment: @martigan no, like in the example, if a ref is again cited nothing happens at the footnote. In fact when a new ref is happening is appears at the footnote. later on if repeated nothing happens, no abbreviation nothing.

Comment: I think I understand. You want a full citation the first time, in a footnote, and a behaviour similar to the supercite command of the numeric style afterwards. You can do it manually by doing a footfullcite the first time, and supercite afterwards. I don't know how to make it automatic however.

Comment: @oo1on I'm pretty sure [this blog entry by Joseph Wright](http://www.texdev.net/2010/03/08/biblatex-numbered-citations-as-footnotes/) will get you most of the way there. Following your previous question about styles, you'd use the options `bibstyle=chem-acs` and `citestyle=numeric-comp`.

Comment: @Audrey @Martigan many thanks to both of you !

Comment: @Audrey: Please turn your comment into an answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Following lockstep's request, here is my comment as an answer. Credit due entirely to [Joseph](http://www.texdev.net/2010/03/08/biblatex-numbered-citations-as-footnotes/).

Be warned that if you want to use footnotes that are not citations, you're going to run into some problems. Joseph recommends [`bigfoot`](http://tug.ctan.org/pkg/bigfoot), but [a commenter](http://www.texdev.net/2010/03/08/biblatex-numbered-citations-as-footnotes/#comments) mentioned that this package has some issues with bugs, compatibility and ongoing support. This problem is examined further in [another question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/20787/4483).

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage[style=chem-acs,hyperref=true,babel=hyphen]{biblatex}

\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{citetracker=true,sorting=none}

% No brackets around the number of each bibliography entry
\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumberwidth}{#1\addperiod}

%---------------------------------------------------------------
% Essentially verbatim from Joseph Wright
% http://www.texdev.net/2010/03/08/biblatex-numbered-citations-as-footnotes/
\makeatletter

\let\cbx@citehook=\empty

\DeclareCiteCommand{\sfcite}[\cbx@superscript]%
  {\usebibmacro{cite:init}%
   \let\multicitedelim=\supercitedelim
   \iffieldundef{prenote}
     {}
     {\BibliographyWarning{Ignoring prenote argument}}%
   \iffieldundef{postnote}
     {}
     {\BibliographyWarning{Ignoring postnote argument}}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{sfcite}%
   \usebibmacro{cite:comp}}
  {}
  {\usebibmacro{cite:dump}}

\newbibmacro*{sfcite}{%
  \ifciteseen
  {}
  {\xappto\cbx@citehook{%
   \noexpand\footnotetext[\thefield{labelnumber}]{%
     \fullcite{\thefield{entrykey}}\addperiod}}}}

\newrobustcmd{\cbx@superscript}[1]{%
  \mkbibsuperscript{#1}%
  \cbx@citehook
  \global\let\cbx@citehook=\empty}

\makeatother
%---------------------------------------------------------------

\bibliography{biblatex-examples}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Title}
\null\vfill\noindent
First citation.\sfcite[cf.][461]{companion}
First citation.\sfcite[e.g.][2589]{bertram}
Second ``multi'' citation.\sfcite{bertram,companion}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Some notes:

- Citation links take you to the bibliography entry, not the footnote. This appears to deviate from a feature you requested in a previous question.
- I've dropped the entry number brackets in the bibliography to conform with your thesis example. A few other changes to this end could be made (e.g. author names in normal font instead of small caps and footnote numbers in superscript), but I personally wouldn't see these as improvements in typographic style.

Comment: this works great and thus I'd like to adapt it for my own use. How would one go about adding `[` and `]` around the cite numbers? (Everywhere: in text superscript, footnote superscript and bibliography).

Comment: @romeovs This is straightforward to do except in the footnote superscripts. Can you post your comment as a question? Be sure to include your document class and `babel` language (if any). I'll be able to answer provided that you are using the standard document classes and your language doesn't impose a particular footnote style.

Comment: it's up! http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20787/biblatex-cite-with-footnote-only-once-with-use-brackets