# Biblatex supercite command with use of square brackets (like a reference style in Wikipedia)

Tags: biblatex

In my report I would like to have the square brackets around the citations as superscripts (like in the Wikipedia style) using `\supercite` command.

The default `\supercite{}` command in `biblatex` package gives a number without brackets.

I have found a good reference in [Biblatex cite with footnote only once, with use of brackets](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20787). However I am interested in such citation style just in normal text - not for the footnotes.

I know that I have to redefine some command but a lack of knowledge does not allow me to complete the task. Could anyone help me?

Comment: This was the top result on google when searching for 'supercite brackets' but a much better version is available [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/114987/biblatex-supercite-with-square-brackets-and-grouped).

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Would this work for you?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{biblatex}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\supercite}[\mkbibsuperscript]
  {\iffieldundef{prenote}
     {}
     {\BibliographyWarning{Ignoring prenote argument}}%
   \iffieldundef{postnote}
     {}
     {\BibliographyWarning{Ignoring postnote argument}}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \bibopenbracket\usebibmacro{cite}\bibclosebracket}
  {\supercitedelim}
  {}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{test.bib}
@book{A01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
}
@book{B02,
  author = {Buthor, B.},
  year = {2002},
  title = {Bravo},
}
@article{C03,
  author = {Cuthor, C.},
  year = {2003},
  title = {Charlie},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{test.bib}

\let\cite=\supercite

\begin{document}

We are citing \supercite{A01,C03} and \supercite{B02} and \cite{C03}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

You can comment out `\let\cite=\supercite` if you don't want `\cite` to behave like `\supercite` (but I thought you might, seeing as it is shorter to write).

For information, what was needed is added `\bibopenbracket` and `\bibclosebracket` around the citation command.

(And I shamelessly stole @lockstep's sample bib file, I pray for forgiveness).

Comment: Thank you very much. Exactly what I wanted. I'm always surprised how short is typical response time here.

Comment: @VladimirS.: If this answers your question, you should mark the answer as accepted by clicking the tick mark next to it. You should also upvote answers and questions that you find useful, by clicking the upward pointing arrow next to the posts.

Comment: Is this solution outdated? I always get the error: `Package biblatex: Bibliography macro 'cite' undefined`

Comment: @ju. Not that I know. Are you using the standard `biblatex` styles? The ``cite` macro is the one called by the `\cite` command, but it could differ in other citation styles. You can still achieve the same result by replacing it with whatever macro you call for citation. Please ask a new question if needed.

Comment: Is there a way to have all numbers in a single bracket, such as [12,13,14] rather than [12],[13],[14] ?

Comment: @user22744 I am not sure this would be feasible easily, and I currently do not have time to work on that issue. Could you please ask a new question and link back to this one? I am sure some Biblatex experts will be able to answer you better (and more quickly) than me.

Comment: @ienissei Thanks a lot for your answer ! I will do asap...

Answer (score 1):

Adding square brackets around the raised citations can be done from the `natbib` [package](http://merkel.zoneo.net/Latex/natbib.php) with one simple command:

```
\usepackage[super,square]{natbib}
```

Comment: Note that `natbib` is incompatible with (read: a "competitor" to) the `biblatex` package. See here for a very detailed discussion: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25701/59034

Comment: This is a useful answer for bibtex users. In fact, I landed here when searching for how to obtain this end result using bibtex.  Can we move/link this answer to a separate question (if such a one doesn't already exist?)