# biblatex supercite wikipedia style with postnotes as footnotes

Tags: biblatex, footnotes, citing

What i want to achieve is a wikipedia style citation (like so [Biblatex supercite command with use of square brackets (like a reference style in Wikipedia)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/60921/biblatex-supercite-command-with-use-of-square-brackets-like-a-reference-style-i) ). At the same time (to handle the problem with add. postnote information) i'd like to to have postnotes i passed along to be added as footnotes. A very nice code snippet for `\supercite` with footnotes has been posted: [Biblatex cite with footnote only once, with use of brackets](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20787/biblatex-cite-with-footnote-only-once-with-use-of-brackets).

So how can i extend the first code snippet to pass postnote arguments to footnotes (in a style that resembles the second code snippet)?

Comment: The second post only prints footnote citations the first time an entry is cited, which means any subsequent postnotes get ignored. Is this really what you want?

Comment: Mh you're right. I'd like to have a footnote every time i pass an optional postnote argument.

Comment: Are you wanting to also avoid recurrent footnotes on the same page? It's probably best to update your post with an example of what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. Upvoting is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you.