# Biblatex supercite with square brackets and grouped

Tags: biblatex

I found this code [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/60921/biblatex-supercite-command-with-use-of-square-brackets-like-a-reference-style-i):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{biblatex}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\supercite}[\mkbibsuperscript]
  {\iffieldundef{prenote}
     {}
     {\BibliographyWarning{Ignoring prenote argument}}%
   \iffieldundef{postnote}
     {}
     {\BibliographyWarning{Ignoring postnote argument}}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \bibopenbracket\usebibmacro{cite}\bibclosebracket}
  {\supercitedelim}
  {}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{test.bib}
@book{A01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
}
@book{B02,
  author = {Buthor, B.},
  year = {2002},
  title = {Bravo},
}
@article{C03,
  author = {Cuthor, C.},
  year = {2003},
  title = {Charlie},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{test.bib}

\let\cite=\supercite

\begin{document}

We are citing \supercite{A01,C03} and \supercite{B02} and \cite{A01,B02,C03}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

which puts the numbers in brackets and in superscript, but i'd like to group them. In the example i get [1],[3] but i want [1,3] and instead of [1],[2],[3] I want [1-3].

Is this possible? And if so, how?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You have to put the commands `\bibopenbracket` and `\bibclosebracket` outsite of the `cite`-loop:

```
\DeclareCiteCommand{\supercite}[\mkbibsuperscript]
  {\iffieldundef{prenote}
     {}
     {\BibliographyWarning{Ignoring prenote argument}}%
   \iffieldundef{postnote}
     {}
     {\BibliographyWarning{Ignoring postnote argument}}%
   \bibopenbracket}%
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cite}}
  {\supercitedelim}
  {\bibclosebracket}
```

---

To get a compact version of the numeric style you can use the style `numeric-comp`. Therefor you need an other modification of `\supercite`.

```
\DeclareCiteCommand{\supercite}[\mkbibsuperscript]
  {\usebibmacro{cite:init}%
   \let\multicitedelim=\supercitedelim
   \iffieldundef{prenote}
     {}
     {\BibliographyWarning{Ignoring prenote argument}}%
   \iffieldundef{postnote}
     {}
     {\BibliographyWarning{Ignoring postnote argument}}%
  \bibopenbracket}%
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cite:comp}}
  {}
  {\usebibmacro{cite:dump}\bibclosebracket}
```

Here the complete MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=numeric-comp]{biblatex}


\DeclareCiteCommand{\supercite}[\mkbibsuperscript]
  {\usebibmacro{cite:init}%
   \let\multicitedelim=\supercitedelim
   \iffieldundef{prenote}
     {}
     {\BibliographyWarning{Ignoring prenote argument}}%
   \iffieldundef{postnote}
     {}
     {\BibliographyWarning{Ignoring postnote argument}}%
  \bibopenbracket}%
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cite:comp}}
  {}
  {\usebibmacro{cite:dump}\bibclosebracket}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{test.bib}
@book{A01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
}
@book{B02,
  author = {Buthor, B.},
  year = {2002},
  title = {Bravo},
}
@article{C03,
  author = {Cuthor, C.},
  year = {2003},
  title = {Charlie},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{test.bib}

\let\cite=\supercite

\begin{document}

We are citing \supercite{A01,C03} and \supercite{B02} and \cite{A01,B02,C03}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]