How can I get the citations inside my \supercite command in one set of square brackets instead of split up in two?
I would like to have my (supercited) citations, if I cite more than one, inside the same set of square brackets. It works if I use the "normal" cite, but not with using \supercite. When using \supercite it splits the citations up in two separate sets of square brackets.
To get my citations supercited I use the following code:
\DeclareCiteCommand{\supercite}[\mkbibsuperscript]
  {\iffieldundef{prenote}
     {}
     {\BibliographyWarning{Ignoring prenote argument}}%
   \iffieldundef{postnote}
     {}
     {\BibliographyWarning{Ignoring postnote argument}}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \bibopenbracket\usebibmacro{cite}\bibclosebracket}
  {\supercitedelim}
  {}\usepackage[sorting=none]{biblatex}
\DeclareCiteCommand{\supercite}[\mkbibsuperscript]
  {\iffieldundef{prenote}
     {}
     {\BibliographyWarning{Ignoring prenote argument}}%
   \iffieldundef{postnote}
     {}
     {\BibliographyWarning{Ignoring postnote argument}}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \bibopenbracket\usebibmacro{cite}\bibclosebracket}
  {\supercitedelim}
  {}


Welcome to tex.sx.

You need to move the brackets out of the loop code ideally into the wrapper as shown in https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/486153/35864.
