# An easier way for capitalizing prenote in citations with biblatex?

Tags: biblatex, capitalization

In this [post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/158911/biblatexbiber-footcite-style-when-using-autocite) I got the advise to use `\autocap{s}ee` within a citation, e.g. `\autocite[\autocap{s}ee][5][ref]` to get context sensitive capitalizing of the letter ‘s’. So if I switch from inline citation to footnote citation the word ‘see’ would be written as ‘See’.

But it is a bit cumbersome to write `\autocap` in all references. Is there a way to integrate this command into for example the `\usebibmacro{pre note}` or to create a new bibmacro like e.g. `prenotecap`? Then I would define:

```
\DeclareCiteCommand{\parencite}[\mkbibparens]
    {\usebibmacro{prenotecap}}
    {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
        \printtext[brackets]{\usebibmacro{cite} \usebibmacro{postnote}}}
    {\multicitedelim}
    {}
```

and I’m done.

Would be nice if someone has a hint how to manage the `\newbibmacro`, because I don’t get the explanation in the biblatex user guide.

**Edit:**
So here is a MWE, which should make it clear what I want to achieve. The word 'see' should be printed as 'See' if I use `autocite=footnote` and 'see' if I use `autocite=inline`. But I don't want to use `\autocap` for each reference.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=alphabetic, autocite=footnote]{biblatex}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\footcite}[\mkbibfootnote]
    {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
    {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
        \printtext[brackets]{\usebibmacro{cite} \usebibmacro{postnote}}}
    {\multicitedelim}
    {}  

\DeclareMultiCiteCommand{\footcites}[\mkbibfootnote]%
    {\footcite}{\multicitedelim}

\DeclareAutoCiteCommand{footnote}[l]{\footcite}{\footcites}

\begin{filecontents*}{bibliography.bib}
@BOOK{Cornelisse1979,
  author = {Cornelisse, J. W. and Schöyer, H. Ferry R. and Wakker, Karel F.},
  title = {Rocket Propulsion and Spaceflight Dynamics},
  year = {1979},
  publisher = {Pitman},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\bibliography{bibliography.bib}

\begin{document}
\null
\vfill

How the citation look like: \autocite[see][35]{Cornelisse1979}
How it should look like: \autocite[\autocap{s}ee][35]{Cornelisse1979}
\end{document}
```

Comment: So `\newcommand*\See{\autocap{s}}` doesn’t fit your needs, because sometimes you want a different word than ‘see’ that is also autocapitalized?

Comment: @Crissov: Exactly. 'See' was only an example. Every word or sentence should work. And the first letter of the first word of the prenote should be capital if it's a footnote citation.

Comment: A full MWE would be helpful here to test what you really want.

Comment: I thought that e.g. `\Cite` etc. would handle this but it seems not. They also don't handle a case where an author's name is lowercase. To get `biblatex` to recognise it as a name, you have to use e.g. `{{lastname}, {firstname}}` in the bib file. But then there is no way to get it capitalised at e.g. the start of a sentence. (I'm never sure what is correct here but I assume that it should be 'Lastname adds...' even though it is 'As noted by lastname...'.) Limitations of `biblatex`'s automatisation of capitalisation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `biblatex` package defines the `\MakeSentenceCase` macro that takes care of the capitalization for you, you just have to tell the bibmacro to use it. I start by defining a field format that uses `\MakeSentenceCase` and then patch the bibmacro to use the field format with the `prenote` field. I use the [`xpatch`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/xpatch) package to do this, but there are lots of ways to patch macros. You just need to add the following code to your preamble when you use `autocite=footnote`.

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{sentencecase}{\MakeSentenceCase{#1}}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchbibmacro{prenote}{\printfield{prenote}}{\printfield[sentencecase]{prenote}}{}{}
```

You will have to remove the code when you use `autocite=inline`. There is probably a way of automatically doing this depending on the value of `autocite`, but I cannot figure out how the option is used.

A full MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=alphabetic, autocite=footnote]{biblatex}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\footcite}[\mkbibfootnote]
    {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
    {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
        \printtext[brackets]{\usebibmacro{cite} \usebibmacro{postnote}}}
    {\multicitedelim}
    {}  

\DeclareFieldFormat{sentencecase}{\MakeSentenceCase{#1}}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchbibmacro{prenote}{\printfield{prenote}}{\printfield[sentencecase]{prenote}}{}{}


\DeclareMultiCiteCommand{\footcites}[\mkbibfootnote]%
    {\footcite}{\multicitedelim}

\DeclareAutoCiteCommand{footnote}[l]{\footcite}{\footcites}

\begin{filecontents*}{bibliography.bib}
@BOOK{Cornelisse1979,
  author = {Cornelisse, J. W. and Schöyer, H. Ferry R. and Wakker, Karel F.},
  title = {Rocket Propulsion and Spaceflight Dynamics},
  year = {1979},
  publisher = {Pitman},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\bibliography{bibliography.bib}

\begin{document}

\null
\vfill

How the citation look like: \autocite[see][35]{Cornelisse1979}
How it should look like: \autocite[\autocap{s}ee][35]{Cornelisse1979}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Sorry I just realised that it doesn't work for `\autocites`, where it prints 'see'. Do you have an idea to solve this last issue?

Comment: I've got it! Just added the following: `\xpatchbibmacro{multiprenote}{\printfield{multiprenote}}{\printfield[sentencecase]{multiprenote}}{}{}`