# Supercite with square brackets

Tags: biblatex, citing

Same requirements as [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/60921/43743). But as soon as I try to set the style option, I get this error (Bibliography macro 'site' undefined):

[image]

MWE (comment the 3rd line in to reproduce the error):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
%\usepackage[style=chem-angew]{biblatex} % fails
\usepackage[]{biblatex}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\supercite}[\mkbibsuperscript]
  {\iffieldundef{prenote}
    {}
    {\BibliographyWarning{Ignoring prenote argument}}%
    \iffieldundef{postnote}
    {}
    {\BibliographyWarning{Ignoring postnote argument}}%
    \bibopenbracket}%
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
    \usebibmacro{cite}}
  {\supercitedelim}
  {\bibclosebracket}

\begin{filecontents}{test.bib}
@book{A01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
}
@book{A02,
    author = {Author, A.},
    year = {2001},
    title = {Alpha},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{test.bib}
\let\cite=\supercite
\begin{document}
Citing \supercite{A01, A02}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Output without style option:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Ok, turns out that the chem-angew style already does everything, if I would just let it.

The problem was that I originally used style chem-acs, which configures superscript references without brackets, which in turn triggered me to go hunting for square bracket hacks.

Just changing the style to chem-angew was all that was needed:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[usenames, dvipsnames]{color}
\hypersetup{pdfpagemode=UseNone, colorlinks, citecolor=Blue, linkcolor=Blue, urlcolor=Blue}
%\usepackage[style=chem-acs]{biblatex}
\usepackage[style=chem-angew]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{test.bib}
@book{A01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
}
@book{A02,
    author = {Author, A.},
    year = {2001},
    title = {Alpha},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{test.bib}

\begin{document}

Citing \autocite{A01, A02}.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

chem-acs: [image]  chem-angew: [image]