# Superscript citations in numeric-comp style

Tags: biblatex

to meet the requirements for our lab reports I need to use a special citation style. It is basically the numeric-comp style from biblatex but the citations shall be superscripts. Everything else is to be the same. As I am using KOMA-Script(documentclass scrartcl), I cannot load the cite-package, because LaTeX tells me they are incompatible.
For now, I used this trick below but that is not a good solution, as I would have to define a new command for every different number of references when multiple citing.

```
\newcommand{\supcite}[1]{$^{\text{\cite{#1}}}$}
```

I am using Biber, if that is relevant.
Does anyone have a solution for this problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Did you try with `biblatex`? It's easier to customise.

Comment: You can use the command `\supercite`. If you insist you can reroute `\cite` to `\supercite`. Note though that in that case you can't use pre- or postnotes.

Comment: Off-topic: They should probably be text superscripts rather than maths superscripts.

Comment: The \supercite command fits my needs except of one thing: The citations are not put in brackets which is needed (and I would prefer it because I am often citing specific data so that the citations might be mixed up with exponents). Is it possible to modify the \supercite command?

Comment: Check out [Biblatex supercite command with use of square brackets (like a reference style in Wikipedia)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/60921/35864). Though you probably need to move those `\bibopenbrackets`/`\bibclosebrackets` a bit, and there are some changes needed for `numeric-comp`, so I have written down the answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use the following redefinition of `\supercite` with just `\bibopenbracket` and `\bibclosebracket` sprinkled in.

```
\DeclareCiteCommand{\supercite}[\mkbibsuperscript]
  {\bibopenbracket
   \usebibmacro{cite:init}%
   \let\multicitedelim=\supercitedelim
   \iffieldundef{prenote}
     {}
     {\BibliographyWarning{Ignoring prenote argument}}%
   \iffieldundef{postnote}
     {}
     {\BibliographyWarning{Ignoring postnote argument}}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cite:comp}}
  {}
  {\usebibmacro{cite:dump}%
   \bibclosebracket}
```

If you replace the `\supercite` above by `\cite` you redefine the standard `\cite` command.