# customize citestyle for biblatex

Tags: biblatex

Just now I'm using

```
\usepackage[backend=biber, citestyle=numeric]{biblatex}

\usepackage[flushmargin]{footmisc}

\newcommand{\myautocite}[2][1]{\autocite[#1]{#2}{\let\thempfn\relax\footnotetext{\autocite{#2} \citeauthor{#2}, \citeyear{#2}, \citetitle{#2}.}}}
```

with the effect that the citation with `\mayautocite{key}` in the text is indeed "[3]" and at the bottom of the page I have the recall "[3] Hilbert, 1901, "The 19th Theorem"".
I have two problems:

--[main] When I use the same reference on a page, this is recalled twice or as many times as it appears, which I don't want. I would like only one recall per page.

--[auxiliary] I don't want the indentation space at the beginning of this recall but would like to keep it for usual footnotes.

Many thanks for pointers on how to achieve that!

Comment: What do you think of my solution in [Help with additional parameter for DeclareCiteCommand](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/274185/35864), that is the second part of the answer? There is quite a lot wrong with your current approach: You should not define a cite command via `\newcommand`, use `\DeclareCiteCommand` instead, you should also never try and combine several `\cite...` commands into one, it will go horrible wrong once you start citing two works.

Comment: Instead of `\fullcite{\thefield{entrykey}}` we can of course have something like `\printfield{labelname}\newunit\printfield{title}\newunit\printfield{year}` (obviously, you would want that to be slightly better more sophisticated to catch some corner cases), let me know if you are interested in that solution and need help modifying it to your needs.

Comment: Many thanks for this (fast!) answer. I have three questions:

Comment: I have three questions: (1) \printfield{author} dos not seem to work ?? (2) I would like the recall to occur at each page. Now it is recalled once, say page 12, but not when it is used again page 133 (3) How can I change \newunits? It gets me a dot when I want a come. Many thanks again ! O.

Comment: \usebibmacro{author} rather than  \printfield{author} solves point (1)

Comment: \renewcommand{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\addspace} solves point (3)

Comment: \makeatletter\renewbibmacro*{cite:comp}{\xde\cbx@citekey{\thefield{entrykey}}\addtocounter{cbx@tempcntb}{1}\ifciteseen{}{\csnumgdef{cbx@instcount\cbx@citekey}{-100}}\ifsamepage{\value{instcount}}{\number\csuse{cbx@instcount\cbx@citekey}}{}{\renewcommand{\@makefntext}[1]{\noindent\normalfont##1}\footnotetext{\printtext[labelnumberwidth]{\printfield{prefixnumber}\printfield{labelnumber}}\addspace

Comment: \renewcommand{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\addspace}\bibfootnotewrapper{%\fullcite{\thefield{entrykey}}\printfield{labelname}\usebibmacro{author}\newunit\printfield{year}\newunit\printfield{title}\addperiod}}}\csnumgdef{cbx@instcount\cbx@citekey}{\value{instcount}}\iffieldundef{shorthand}{\ifbool{bbx:subentry}{\iffieldundef{entrysetcount}{\usebibmacro{cite:comp:comp}}{\usebibmacro{cite:comp:inset}}}{\usebibmacro{cite:comp:comp}}}{\usebibmacro{cite:comp:shand}}}\makeatletter

Comment: I put the answer in two comments with no spaces as it was too long otherwise ????

Comment: The header:\usepackage[%
    backend=biber,
    style=numeric-comp,
    citetracker=true,
    pagetracker=true,
    ]{biblatex}

Comment: Maybe you could clean up your comments here since you have written up an answer that contains the code in a proper format.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code that does the job.

```
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[%
    backend=biber,
    style=numeric-comp,
    citetracker=true,
    pagetracker=true,
    ]{biblatex}

\makeatletter
\renewbibmacro*{cite:comp}{%
  \xdef\cbx@citekey{\thefield{entrykey}}%
  \addtocounter{cbx@tempcntb}{1}%
  \ifciteseen
    {}
    {\csnumgdef{cbx@instcount\cbx@citekey}{-100}}%  
  \ifsamepage{\value{instcount}}{\number\csuse{cbx@instcount\cbx@citekey}}%
    {}
    {\renewcommand{\@makefntext}[1]{\noindent\normalfont##1}%
     \footnotetext{
       \printtext[labelnumberwidth]{%
         \printfield{prefixnumber}%
         \printfield{labelnumber}}%
       \addspace
       \renewcommand{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\addspace}
       \bibfootnotewrapper{%\fullcite{\thefield{entrykey}}%
         \printfield{labelname}\usebibmacro{author}\newunit\printfield{year}\newunit\printfield{title}\addperiod}}}%
   \csnumgdef{cbx@instcount\cbx@citekey}{\value{instcount}}%
   \iffieldundef{shorthand}
    {\ifbool{bbx:subentry}
       {\iffieldundef{entrysetcount}
          {\usebibmacro{cite:comp:comp}}
          {\usebibmacro{cite:comp:inset}}}
       {\usebibmacro{cite:comp:comp}}}
    {\usebibmacro{cite:comp:shand}}}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\myautocite}[2][1]{\cite[#1]{#2}}
```

Comment: I don't think the last `\newcommand{\myautocite}[2][1]{\cite[#1]{#2}}` is a good idea, it destroys the pre-/post-note abilities partially. When I made my comment above I should have said `\printnames{labelname}`, that however only works with the option `labelname` passed to `biblatex`.

Comment: It would also be great if you could give attribution to the solutions you used, I suspect the "same page test" is from [biblatex: is there a command analogous to \ifciteseen but within one page?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/35673/35864)?

Comment: The newcommand{\myautocite} ... is a blunder, just using \autocite is enough. And I couldn't find again the page I was using, so thanks for having found it!

Comment: If you think your answer answers the question, consider accepting it so the question gets marked as solved.