# Changing biblatex footcite style to use square brackets and the number of the bibliography

Tags: biblatex, footnotes, citing

Im writing a paper using biblatex where I want to make it easier for the reader to check the name and author from bibliography in the same page, up to now i have been using `\cite` go get the references from the bibliography as a `[1]` and `\footnote` as intended to write text at the bottom of the page,

> This is the note\footnote{content} and this is the cite \footcite{Wuldart}.

Whenever i use a footnote and a footcite I get something like this and of course the numbers reset every page

[image]

I actually want the  `\footcite` command to show

> [Number at bibliography] [Author] [Title]

and something like this should come out at the foot of the page

[image]

Notice how `footnote` wasnt affected by the change, Im trying to find a way to redefine footnote to do this,  this way the reader doesnt have to move all over the document just to check the name of the source and he will only do it if he actually wants to review the complete information/url of the source

Im currently using

```
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authortitle, citestyle=reading  ]{biblatex}
```

However i lack the knowlege to redefine the footcite to do what Im loking for

Comment: Welcome! Please provide a complete example we can compile to reproduce your situation. This is much more useful than mere fragments of code. An example in this case should include a `.bib` entry, of course. The main document should start `\documentclass` and end `end{document}`. Otherwise, we have no idea what is happening at the moment and can't help much. For example, what do you mean that 'of course' the numbers reset every page? Not by default they don't!

Comment: Incidentally, I think this would be very, very confusing for readers. I strongly recommend not doing it.

Comment: Maybe one of [customize citestyle for biblatex](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/275423/35864), [Biblatex cite with footnote only once, with use of brackets](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/20787/35864), [Biblatex supercite command with use of square brackets (like a reference style in Wikipedia)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/60921/35864), [Help with additional parameter for DeclareCiteCommand](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/274073/35864) can help you

Comment: What I don't quite understand from your question is what `\footcite` ought to do in the text (it does give a full footnote citation, but does it have to leave just a footnote marker (probably not) or the citation number either in brackets or as superscript?)

Comment: Would it be possible to get the above questions answered? I'm quite sure what you are asking for is fairly straightforward to implement, but there are some details I'm not sure about. It would be a waste if someone were to give an answer that does not do what you want.

Comment: @moewe What `\footcite` actually does depends on what style is defined `\usepackage[backend=biber, style=ieee,citestyle=reading]{biblatex}`, as you can see in [link](https://es.sharelatex.com/learn/Biblatex_citation_styles) there are several styles avaiable, none of them does what i want, which is, make footcite work as a replacement of `\cite{}`, Whenever i cite it shows a pair of brackets and the number of the reference, I want to make `\footcite` show that number in brackets followed by a footnote with that number, and the entire reference from the bibfile i.e [1] Name - Reference - Year

Comment: Your description makes me think you want [Biblatex cite with footnote only once, with use of brackets](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/20787/35864) or the second solution from [Help with additional parameter for DeclareCiteCommand](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/274073/35864). It would be helpful if you could explain exactly what you don't like about the approaches, should that not be the case.

Comment: Since you didn't get back with any complaints and the answer is a very good fit, I will vote to close as a duplicate of [Biblatex cite with footnote only once, with use of brackets](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/20787/35864) soon.