# (full)footcite with brackets

Tags: biblatex, biber

Is there a way to

```
\footcite{key}
```

or

```
\fullfootcite{key}
```

such that in the text there are no upper index numbers but numbers enclosed in brackets? Correspondingly, the *footnote* citation should begin with (e.g.)

```
[1]
```

and not with an upper index number.

Comment: Would that number then be the normal footnote number or the label number of the citation in a `numeric` context? What style are you using?

Comment: It would be the normal footnote number. In my current document I did not set any style. In preamble: `\usepackage[doi=false and other options alike]{biblatex}`, `\bibliography{mybibfile}`, `\renewcommand*{\thefootnote}{\arabic{footnote}}` (to override the result of some huge template file which is used by `\input`). In the document I am using `\footfullcite{key}`.

Comment: And what do you do about normal footnotes? Do they have the same counter, but remain little superscripts? Or should they come down and be wrapped in brackets as well?

Comment: It does not matter what happens to normal footnotes since I am not intending to use any.

Comment: Aha, but then you could use the code from http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/274185/35864 or http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/20819/35864.

Comment: That looks good. Thank you and sorry for my bad research.

Comment: With things like this it is *really* hard to find the right terms to search let alone duplicate questions, so don't worry about it. Let me know which of those answers worked for you or if you need something changed. (But then it would be helpful to show a MWE of what you have so far.)

Comment: Weird behavior: 1) If one changes document type of the MWE in http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/274185/35864 to beamer, it says **test.tex:0: name{cite.0@mybibkey} has been referenced but does not exist, replaced by a fixed one**. 2) if I paste that code into my large document with big `\input`s (template at my office), it works somehow works but the footnotes' numbers are in parentheses. The in-text citations have correct brackets.

Comment: The warnings are just because you don't have a `\printbibliography`, a click on the citation label would take you there. The round brackets is because `biblatex` can't detect footnotes with beamer as a short work-around add `\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumberwidth}{[#1]}`.

Comment: Now I'm almost there. Still two issues: 1) compiler says **Patching footnotes failed.** 2) inline brackets have leading spaces, e.g. `[  13]`. Footnote brackets look nice.

Comment: You can ignore the "patching footnotes failed" warning (it is the one I referred to above, `biblatex` will not be able to detect that you are in a footnote, but that is not important for us any more). The code doesn't give me spaces in the citations. Did you copy the exact code from the other question or did you modify anything?

Comment: Solved but not understood: each of the three clear commands in `\AtEveryCitekey{ \clearfield{month} \clearfield{type} \clearlist{institution} }` in the preamble adds a blank both in the inline brackets (`[   13]` (only one space shown here due to stackexchange limitations)) and between the footnote brackets and the actual citation text (author names, in my case).

Comment: I assume the `\AtEveryCitekey{ \clearfield{month} \clearfield{type} \clearlist{institution} }` has line breaks in your actual code? If so you need to end the line with `%` to make sure that no spurious white space is introduced. See [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7453/35864).