# Redefine the \footcite command with biblatex to print only first author's surname and title

Tags: beamer, biblatex, citing

In order to limit the space occupied by citations in a beamer presentation, I would like to limit the list of authors to print only the first surname when used in the footnotes field, but I struggle in finding a way to do that.

Starting from [Uniform citation numbers in Beamer with Biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/396738/uniform-citation-numbers-in-beamer-with-biblatex), how to modify the hypercite bibmacro in the MWE to print only selected fields, i.e. first author's surname and title?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{MWE.bib}
@article{Knuth92,
        author = "D.E. Knuth",
        title = "Two notes on notation",
        journal = "Amer. Math. Monthly",
        volume = "99",
        year = "1992",
        pages = "403--422",
}

@book{ConcreteMath,
        author = "R.L. Graham and D.E. Knuth and O. Patashnik",
        title = "Concrete mathematics",
        publisher = "Addison-Wesley",
        address = "Reading, MA",
        year = "1989"
}

@unpublished{Simpson,
        author = "H. Simpson",
        title = "Proof of the {R}iemann {H}ypothesis",
        note = "preprint (2003), available at
        \texttt{http://www.math.drofnats.edu/riemann.ps}",
        year = "2003"
}
\end{filecontents}

\usetheme[progressbar=frametitle,numbering=fraction]{metropolis}
\setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}{\insertbiblabel} %% Remove book symbol from references and add number
\usepackage[style=ieee,backend=bibtex,citetracker=true]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{MWE.bib}

% See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/396754/28146
\makeatletter
\newbibmacro*{hypercite}{%
  \renewcommand{\@makefntext}[1]{\noindent\normalfont##1}%
  \footnotetext{%
    \blxmkbibnote{foot}{%
    \printtext[labelnumberwidth]{%
      \printfield{prefixnumber}%
      \printfield{labelnumber}}%
    \addspace
    \fullcite{\thefield{entrykey}}}}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\hypercite}%
  {\usebibmacro{cite:init}}
  {\usebibmacro{hypercite}}
  {}
  {\usebibmacro{cite:dump}}

% Redefine the \footcite command to use the reference number
\renewcommand{\footcite}[1]{\cite{#1}\hypercite{#1}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Some references}
Some references non cited in the footnotes, \cite{Knuth92,Simpson,ConcreteMath} and some cited also in the footnotes\footnote{A footnote}, \footcite{Knuth92} and \footcite{ConcreteMath}\footnote{A second footnote}
\end{frame}


\begin{frame}[t,allowframebreaks]{References} %% Aligned top
\printbibliography[heading=none]
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To print only the first author's surname in the footnote, you could use the quick and dirty way and use `\printnames[][1-1]{author}`.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{MWE.bib}
@article{Knuth92,
        author = "D.E. Knuth",
        title = "Two notes on notation",
        journal = "Amer. Math. Monthly",
        volume = "99",
        year = "1992",
        pages = "403--422",
}

@book{ConcreteMath,
        author = "R.L. Graham and D.E. Knuth and O. Patashnik",
        title = "Concrete mathematics",
        publisher = "Addison-Wesley",
        address = "Reading, MA",
        year = "1989"
}

@unpublished{Simpson,
        author = "H. Simpson",
        title = "Proof of the {R}iemann {H}ypothesis",
        note = "preprint (2003), available at
        \texttt{http://www.math.drofnats.edu/riemann.ps}",
        year = "2003"
}
\end{filecontents}

\usetheme[progressbar=frametitle,numbering=fraction]{metropolis}
\setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}{\insertbiblabel} %% Remove book symbol from references and add number
\usepackage[style=ieee,backend=bibtex,citetracker=true]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{MWE.bib}

% See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/396754/28146
\makeatletter
\newbibmacro*{hypercite}{%
  \renewcommand{\@makefntext}[1]{\noindent\normalfont##1}%
  \footnotetext{%
    \blxmkbibnote{foot}{%
    \printtext[labelnumberwidth]{%
      \printfield{prefixnumber}%
      \printfield{labelnumber}}%
    \addspace
    \printnames[][1-1]{author}
    \setunit{\addcomma\addspace}
    \printfield{title}}}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\hypercite}%
  {\usebibmacro{cite:init}}
  {\usebibmacro{hypercite}}
  {}
  {\usebibmacro{cite:dump}}

% Redefine the \footcite command to use the reference number
\renewcommand{\footcite}[1]{\cite{#1}\hypercite{#1}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Some references}
Some references non cited in the footnotes, \cite{Knuth92,Simpson,ConcreteMath} and some cited also in the footnotes\footnote{A footnote}, \footcite{Knuth92} and \footcite{ConcreteMath}\footnote{A second footnote}
\end{frame}


\begin{frame}[t,allowframebreaks]{References} %% Aligned top
\printbibliography[heading=none]
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Just as a curiosity, is there a general way to search in the biblatex manual? With biblatex I find myself quite lost, much much more than with the Tikz manual, I don't know why...

Comment: For example, why `\setunit{\addcomma\addspace}`?

Comment: @Alex Probably there good way to search it - however I am not one of the few enlightened people :)

Comment: @Alex `\setunit{\addcomma\addspace}` is something I learned from reading the source of existing biblatex styles rather then look it up in the manual. Another good learning resource is to read as many answers by https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/35864/moewe as possible.