# biblatex footcite with familyname only

Tags: biblatex, footnotes

This [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/20819/371) is really great but I am trying unsuccessfully so far to remove the author's firstname in the footnote entries only. For instance, I have tried to tweak the `\AtEveryCitekey` hook, but again with no success.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code you are using uses `\fullcite` for the full citations, we can change the name format there as follows

```
\DeclareNameFormat{family}{%
  \usebibmacro{name:family}
    {\namepartfamily}
    {\namepartgiven}
    {\namepartprefix}
    {\namepartsuffix}%
  \usebibmacro{name:andothers}}
\DeclareCiteCommand{\fullcite}
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usedriver
     {\DeclareNameAlias{author}{family}\DeclareNameAlias{editor}{family}\DeclareNameAlias{translator}{family}}
     {\thefield{entrytype}}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}
```

Comment: Thanks. I had to replace your `\usebibmacro{name:family-given}{\namepartfamily}{\namepartgiven}{\namepartprefix}{\namepartsuffix}` by `\usebibmacro{name:family-given}{\namepartfamily}{\relax}{\namepartprefix}{\namepartsuffix}`

Comment: @pluton Oh, sorry, it should have been `\usebibmacro{name:family}`, then there is no need to replace the `\namepartgi‌​ven` by `\relax`. I have fixed that in the edit now.