# BibLatex modification: no small caps in authors

Tags: biblatex, small-caps

When using the code from [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20637/biblatex-which-style-for-a-footnote-once-then-nothing), I get the names of authors in small caps. Is it possible to have it in normal text ?

The MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{memoir}

%% -1- Encoding Stuff
% input encoding with utf8
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
% Use T1 Fonts
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
% URL package
\usepackage{url}
% Footnotes stick at the bottom of the page, not the bottom of the text
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}
% Custom quotes (French style)
\usepackage{csquotes}
% Links in the pdf
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,unicode]{hyperref}
% Babel --> Français !
\usepackage[francais]{babel}

%% -2- About Bibliography
% Load BibLaTeX
\usepackage[style=chem-acs,% Citation style
            hyperref=true,% Links to citations in the pdf
            babel=hyphen,% For hyphenation patterns
            backend=biber,% Use Biber. Probably better. If unavailable, switch this to bibtex
            refsection=chapter% Per chapter bibliography
           ]{biblatex}

% All BibLaTeX setup taken almost straight from Tex.SX:
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20754/tuning-numbered-citations-as-footnote

% Setup options
\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{%
  citetracker=true,% Citation tracker enabled in order not to repeat citations, and have two lists.
  sorting=none,% Don't sort, just print in the order of citation
  alldates=long,% Long dates, so we can tweak them at will afterwards
  dateabbrev=false,% Remove abbreviations in dates, for same reason as ``alldates=long''
  articletitle=true,% To have article titles in full bibliography
  maxcitenames=999% Number of names before replacing with et al. Here, everyone.
}

% No brackets around the number of each bibliography entry
\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumberwidth}{#1\addperiod}

% Suppress article title, doi, url, etc. in citations
\AtEveryCitekey{%
  \ifentrytype{article}
    {\clearfield{title}}
    {}%
  \clearfield{doi}%
  \clearfield{url}%
  \clearlist{publisher}%
  \clearlist{location}%
  \clearfield{note}%
}

% Print year instead of date, when available; make use of urldate
\DeclareFieldFormat{urldate}{\bibstring{urlseen}\space#1}
\renewbibmacro*{date}{% Based on date bib macro from chem-acs.bbx
  \iffieldundef{year}
    {\ifentrytype{online}
       {\printtext[urldate]{\printurldate}}
       {\printtext[date]{\printdate}}}
    {\printfield[date]{year}}}

% Remove period from titles
\DeclareFieldFormat*{title}{#1}

% Embed doi and url in titles, when available
\renewbibmacro*{title}{% Based on title bib macro from biblatex.def
  \ifboolexpr{ test {\iffieldundef{title}}
               and test {\iffieldundef{subtitle}} }
    {}
    {\ifboolexpr{ test {\ifhyperref}
                  and not test {\iffieldundef{doi}} }
       {\href{http://dx.doi.org/\thefield{doi}}
          {\printtext[title]{%
             \printfield[titlecase]{title}%
             \setunit{\subtitlepunct}%
             \printfield[titlecase]{subtitle}}}}
       {\ifboolexpr{ test {\ifhyperref}
                     and not test {\iffieldundef{url}} }
         {\href{\thefield{url}}
            {\printtext[title]{%
               \printfield[titlecase]{title}%
               \setunit{\subtitlepunct}%
               \printfield[titlecase]{subtitle}}}}
         {\printtext[title]{%
            \printfield[titlecase]{title}%
            \setunit{\subtitlepunct}%
            \printfield[titlecase]{subtitle}}}}%
     \newunit}%
  \printfield{titleaddon}%
  \clearfield{doi}%
  \clearfield{url}%
  \ifentrytype{article}% Delimit article and journal titles with a period
    {\adddot}
    {}}

%---------------------------------------------------------------
% Essentially verbatim from Joseph Wright
% http://www.texdev.net/2010/03/08/biblatex-numbered-citations-as-footnotes/
% --> Create macro sfcite to have both citations in footnotes and at the end.
\makeatletter

% Create sfcite command
\DeclareCiteCommand{\sfcite}[\cbx@superscript]%
  {\usebibmacro{cite:init}%
   \let\multicitedelim=\supercitedelim
   \iffieldundef{prenote}
     {}
     {\BibliographyWarning{Ignoring prenote argument}}%
    \iffieldundef{postnote}
     {}
     {\BibliographyWarning{Ignoring postnote argument}}%
  }
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{sfcite}%
   \usebibmacro{cite:comp}}
  {}
  {\usebibmacro{cite:dump}}

% Add entry to bibliography
\newbibmacro*{sfcite}{%
  \ifciteseen
  {}
  {\xappto\cbx@citehook{%
   \noexpand\footnotetext[\thefield{labelnumber}]{%
     \fullcite{\thefield{entrykey}}\addperiod}}}}

% Superscript
\newrobustcmd{\cbx@superscript}[1]{%
  \mkbibsuperscript{#1}%
  \cbx@citehook%
  \global\let\cbx@citehook=\empty}
\let\cbx@citehook=\empty

\makeatother
%---------------------------------------------------------------

% To have footnotes going well with citations --> \vfootnote
\long\def\vfootnote#1{%
  \begingroup%
  \def\thefootnote{\roman{footnote}}\footnote{#1}%
  \endgroup}

% Bibliography as a section rather than chapter
\defbibheading{bibliography}[\bibname]{%
  \section{#1}%
%  \markboth{#1}{#1}%
}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{ref1,
    hyphenation = {american},
    title = {Natural Products as Sources of New Drugs over the Last 25 Years},
    author = {Newman, D.J. and Cragg, G.M.},
    journal = {J. of Nat. Prod.},
    volume = {70},
    number = {3},
    pages = {461--477},
    year = {2007}}
@article{ref2,
    hyphenation = {american},
    title = {Natural products as leads to potential drugs: an old process or the new hope for drug discovery?},
    author = {Newman, D.J.},
    journal = {J. of Med. Chem.},
    volume = {51},
    number = {9},
    pages = {2589--2599},
    year = {2008}}
@online{ref3,
    author = {Quintin, C.},
    title = {Les eponges},
    url = {http://christophe.quintin.pagesperso-orange.fr/Liste_Doc.html},
    urldate = {2009-05-03}
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}


\begin{document}

Test Test test

First citation.\sfcite{ref1,ref2} Some text\vfootnote{A footnote}.


\pagebreak
Second citation\sfcite{ref1}, second citation\sfcite{ref2}, first citation.\sfcite{ref3}
\printbibliography


\end{document}
```