# Fresh citation numbers for each chapter: footnote citation using \sfcite

Tags: biblatex

I am using the technique to add citations on each page as footnote as given [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20754/tuning-numbered-citations-as-footnote). It works very nicely, but I would like to tweak it such that at every new chapter it starts labeling the citations from 1 again. At the moment it keeps on numbering the citations one after the other over all the chapters, which means the last chapters have citations all in 3 digits, which look not so nice.

Is there a way to start fresh citations at each chapter?

-Thanks!
Here is the code I am using:

```
\usepackage{manyfoot}

\AtEveryCitekey{\clearfield{title}\clearfield{note}\clearfield{volume}\clearfield{eprint}}
% \usepackage{hyperref}               
\hypersetup{%
    colorlinks,
    linkcolor={red!0!black},
    citecolor={blue!0!black},
    urlcolor={blue!80!black}
}

\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{citetracker=true,sorting=none,maxcitenames=3,doi=false,url=false,isbn=false,hyperref=true,backref=false}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{ngerman}{
   andothers = {\textit{et~al\adddot}}            
}

% Citation footnotes: use \footnoteA
\DeclareNewFootnote{A}

% Vanilla footnotes: use \footnoteB
\DeclareNewFootnote{B}

% Number of each bibliography entry in brackets
\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumberwidth}{\mkbibbrackets{#1}}


\newtoggle{cbx@togcite}

% Citation number superscript in brackets
\renewcommand\@makefntext[1]{%
  \iftoggle{cbx@togcite}
    {\@textsuperscript{\normalfont[\@thefnmark]}\enspace #1}
    {\@textsuperscript{\normalfont\@thefnmark}\enspace #1}%
  \global\togglefalse{cbx@togcite}}

% Citation number superscript in brackets (for babel french)
\ifdef{\@makefntextFB}{%
\renewcommand\@makefntextFB[1]{%
  \iftoggle{cbx@togcite}
    {\@textsuperscript{\normalfont[\@thefnmark]}\enspace #1}
    {\@textsuperscript{\normalfont\@thefnmark}\enspace #1}%
  \global\togglefalse{cbx@togcite}}}{}


\DeclareCiteCommand{\sfcite}[\cbx@superscript]%
  {\usebibmacro{cite:init}%
   \let\multicitedelim=\supercitedelim
   \iffieldundef{prenote}
     {}
     {\BibliographyWarning{Ignoring prenote argument}}%
   \iffieldundef{postnote}
     {}
     {\BibliographyWarning{Ignoring postnote argument}}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{sfcite}%
   \usebibmacro{cite:comp}}
  {}
  {\usebibmacro{cite:dump}}

\newbibmacro*{sfcite}{%
  \ifciteseen
  {}
  {\xappto\cbx@citehook{%
   \global\toggletrue{cbx@togcite}%
   \noexpand\footnotetextA[\thefield{labelnumber}]{%
     \fullcite{\thefield{entrykey}}\addperiod}}}}

\newrobustcmd{\cbx@superscript}[1]{%
  \mkbibsuperscript{\mkbibbrackets{#1}}%
  \cbx@citehook%
  \global\let\cbx@citehook=\empty}

\let\cbx@citehook=\empty
%---------------------------------------------------------------

\makeatother

\newbibmacro{string+doiurlisbn}[1]{%
  \iffieldundef{doi}{%
    \iffieldundef{url}{%
      \iffieldundef{isbn}{%
        \iffieldundef{issn}{%
          #1%
        }{%
          \href{}{#1}%
        }%
      }{%
        \href{}{#1}%
      }%
    }{%
      \href{\thefield{url}}{#1}%
    }%
  }{%
    \href{\thefield{doi}}{#1}%
  }%
}

\DeclareFieldFormat{journaltitle}{\usebibmacro{string+doiurlisbn}{\mkbibemph{#1}}}
```

Comment: Further info: I am using one single .bib file for all the chapters and chapters are included as separate files.

Answer (score 1):

Solved: I need to just add `refsection=chapter` in the `\usepackage`
like this.

```
\usepackage[refsection=chapter,backend=biber,style=numeric-comp,mcite, url=false, subentry]{biblatex}
```

And now it starts with new citation numbers on each chapter.