# biblatex footnote references

Tags: biblatex, footnotes, citing

Another migrating to biblatex type question.

In my thesis I have used something called the `footbib` package. What this lets me do is create citations in the text, in some regular way, only the reference list appears as a footnote under a line covering the length of the page.

It is implemented using a separate .aux file that has to be processed separately to the main .aux file for the document.

The command to add such a citation is `\footcite{<key>}`

biblatex also has a command called this, but it doesn't seem to do the same thing. The biblatex version seems to use use a number in the body of the text and then a longer citation index in the footnote (the reference to it is still in the main references section).

Now as the commands have the same name, this screams of incompatibility and even if I called `\usepackage{footbib}` after `biblatex`. There could be not immediately noticed problems caused (and it might not work at all).

So the question is, how do I do what I want to do with biblatex. It might make matters easier that I only want to do this on one page at the beginning of my thesis. I gather there is a `refsection` command or environment that might do it, but I'm not sure it is the right thing.

Comment: This might [duplicate a previous question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/20637/4483), but without a concrete example it is hard to tell.

Comment: @Audrey. I don't think this is a duplicate. What, I think, he is trying to achieve, is to make, for a special chapter or section or whatever part of his work, a bibliography, limited to this part, appear as a footnote of, presumely, the last page of this special chapter or whatever part of text. Correct me if I'm wrong aghsmith. Wether it is possible to do this by combining refsection and putting a printbibliography inside a classical footnote I cannot try for the moment. Perhaps other people may hav thought of the problem.

Comment: Ah, I've only just found that people commented on this. I Martigan, yes, you are correct. It's actually just on one page that i want to limit the references to. I've tried an approach like this but will generate a new question regarding this matter.

Comment: @aghsmith Any chance this post could be flagged for closure now that your new question has been answered? It would knock another question off the unanswered list.

Comment: yep, sorry i forget to tick the box to tell me when someone has added a comment to my question.