# biblatex-chem warning: Macro 'institution+location+date' already defined. What does it mean and how do I get rid of it?

Tags: biblatex, warnings, chemstyle

As a rule of thumb, I aim to make my latex compilations complete without errors or warnings. I've come to accept some underful badboxes as unavoidable though :(

I'm trying to change over to `biblatex`, as evidence by several of my other posts.

With a rather stripped down code I am given this warning message, when I compile:

```
Package biblatex Warning: Macro 'institution+location+date' already defined.
(biblatex)                Using \renewbibmacro.
```

But don't really know what it means or how to sort it.

I can provide more info in necessary, but it could get rather cumbersome.

I am using a custom `.cls` file, partially handed down to me and partially modified by me. It's based on the `book` class. I have searched for the word "institution" in it (not as whole word only), with no success.

So if someone has some knowledge of this and how I might resolve the warning then please let me know. If you need some more info then hopefully I can help there too.

EDIT: I'm also using the `chem-rsc` biblatex package option.

EDIT: The following would appear to be a VERY minimal working example of the bug/feature/eccentricity:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[style=chem-rsc]{biblatex}
\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From your [earlier](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29298/using-biblatex-i-want-to-have-a-section-where-references-are-given-as-footnotes) question, I infer that you are using the style `chem-rsc` which is part of [biblatex-chem](http://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-chem). I took a look into `chem-rsc.bbx` and indeed found the following code snippet:

```
\newbibmacro*{institution+location+date}{%
  \printlist{institution}%
  \newunit
  \printlist{location}%
  \newunit
  \usebibmacro{date}%
  \newunit
}
```

Because the `institution+location+date` bibmacro is already defined in the `biblatex` core file `standard.bbx`, and because `chem-rsc.bbx` (like most bibliography styles) eventually relates to `standard.bbx`, this seems to be a bug in `biblatex-chem`.

Comment: Then we should change the title of this question. At the moment the relation to `biblatex-chem` is missing.

Comment: @Marco: As soon as aghsmith confirms my suspicion, I'll add the [tag:chemstyle] tag. We could also amend the question title.

Comment: In this way we increase the chance that Joseph will read this question.

Comment: @lockstep, thanks for this, I think you went a bit above and beyond by checking my previous posts. I had started doing checking through all the latex packages, but missed out the `chem-rsc` style because it had been placed in my user area instead of the main package repository. I'd be happy to try and report this bug myself, but you found and identified it, perhaps you would like to do the honours? else I'll have a go. Cheers.

Comment: @aghsmith: I'll change question title and tags, you report the bug. :-)

Comment: `biblatex` does not issue a 'hard' error for `\renew...`, unlike the kernel, so these things are a bit harder to pick up. I've altered the appropriate lines, and CTAN will be updated shortly.

Answer (score 4):

The warning is clear. Somewhere you make something like

```
\newbibmacro*{institution+location+date}
```

but this macro already exists. So you must change it to

```
\renewbibmacro*{institution+location+date}
```

Comment: though technically correct I was hoping for something more insightful. I was aware that I had not defined a macro by this name, myself. I had guessed that it had arisen based on a conflict within packages, possibly involving the book class, which I have since checked. I guess it did inspire me to start checking the internals of other packages, so I up voted your comment.

Comment: @aghsmith: The problem: You haven't provide a minimal example and your information are very spare.

Comment: yes this is true. I guess I was hoping that this problem would ring bells with someone and they would immediately know what the matter was. I will try and produce a minimal example as a reference.