# Biblatex[-chicago, authordate] footnote on first cite. Extra space put in parencite

Tags: spacing, biblatex, citing, chicago-style

Following http://www.texdev.net/2010/03/08/biblatex-numbered-citations-as-footnotes/ I made the following minimal example, that put the full citation in a margin note for the first time, when using `biblatex-chicago` authordate style:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[citetracker=true,ibidtracker=false,authordate]{biblatex-chicago}
\bibliography{biblatex-examples}
\makeatletter
\DeclareCiteCommand{\parencite}[\mkbibparens]
  {\usebibmacro{cite:init}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{notefullcite}%
   \usebibmacro{cite}}
  {}%\setunit{\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\newbibmacro*{notefullcite}{%
  \ifciteseen
    {}
    {\nopunct\unspace\marginpar{%
    \usedriver{}{%
        \thefield{entrytype}}.}}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

Text \parencite{hammond}.

Text \parencite{cotton,hammond}.

Some filler text \parencite{cotton}.

Some text\parencite{cotton}.

Text \parencite{cotton,hammond}.

\end{document}
```

But with this code, before the first time a parencite is used for a citation, biblatex put a extra space after "(".

[image]

I tried to find the origin of this space, but I failed. I hoped that the `\unspace` remove it but not. I think this space is generated by `\printnames` from the `cmsbracketname` macro, but I don't know what to do =[.

I'm using:

- % $Id: biblatex-chicago.sty,v 0.1.1.31 2011/02/15 11:56:42 dfussner Exp $
- % $Id: chicago-authordate15.bbx,v 0.8.1.2 2011/09/21 10:53:07 dfussner Exp $
- % $Id: chicago-authordate15.cbx,v 0.8.1.4 2011/09/21 10:53:18 dfussner Exp $
- % $Id: biblatex.sty,v 1.6 2011/07/29 19:21:28 lehman stable $

Comment: Your link doesn't seem to work. I get a `Error establishing a database connection` message.

Comment: Uhh, it's become offline after I posted the question. The contents is basically the same as the answer from Audrey from http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20637/biblatex-which-style-for-a-footnote-once-then-nothing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the following definition:

```
\newbibmacro*{notefullcite}{%
  \ifciteseen%
    {}%
    {\marginpar{%
    \usedriver{}{%
        \thefield{entrytype}}\finentry}}}
```

Here the complete example with the result:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[citetracker=true,ibidtracker=false,authordate]{biblatex-chicago}
\bibliography{biblatex-examples}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\parencite}[\mkbibparens]
  {\usebibmacro{cite:init}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{notefullcite}%
   \usebibmacro{cite}}
  {}%\setunit{\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\newbibmacro*{notefullcite}{%
  \ifciteseen%
    {}%
    {\marginpar{%
    \usedriver{}{%
        \thefield{entrytype}}\finentry}}}

\begin{document}

Text \parencite{hammond}.

Text \parencite{cotton,hammond}.

Some filler text \parencite{cotton}.

Some text\parencite{cotton}.

Text \parencite{cotton,hammond}.

\end{document}
```

[image]