# Extra space after ( using parencite with biblatex package in beamer

Tags: beamer, biblatex, citing

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=ieee,citestyle=authoryear]{biblatex}

\bibliography{literature.bib}

\begin{document}
    network design\parencite{sb2016}
\end{document}
```

Now it produces something like this:
[image]

Notice there is a space between the ( and the author's name.

I tried this: [Biblatex[-chicago, authordate] footnote on first cite. Extra space put in parencite](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30003/biblatex-chicago-authordate-footnote-on-first-cite-extra-space-put-in-parenc) But it tells me that the cite:init is not defined.

I've never come across this question before. I even updated the required packages to see if it corrects the error. No it didn't work. Weird.

Update: bibentry

```
@article{sb2016,
  title={Strategic design of public bicycle sharing systems with service level constraints},
  author={Lin, Jenn-Rong and Yang, Ta-Hui},
  journal={Transportation research part E: logistics and transportation review},
  volume={47},
  number={2},
  pages={284--294},
  year={2011},
  publisher={Elsevier}
}
```

I am using biblatex package version 3.7. And biber 2.7.

Update: With article and its log file

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[UTF8]{ctexcap}

%-------------------------------------------------------
% INCLUDE PACKAGES
%-------------------------------------------------------

\usepackage{extramarks} % Required for headers and footers
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required to insert images
\usepackage{tikz} % Required for tikz picture
\usetikzlibrary{fit,arrows,calc,positioning}
\usepackage{xcolor} % Required for color setting
\newcommand{\highlight}[1]{%
  \colorbox{red!20}{$\displaystyle#1$}}
\usepackage{amssymb} % Required for math fonts
\usepackage{amsmath} % Required for math notation
\usepackage{mathtools} % Required for math notation
\usepackage{float} % Stop float
\usepackage[timeinterval=1]{tdclock} % Required for clock
\usepackage{mdframed} % Required to change backgroud colour, but no floating support
\usepackage{pgfpages} % Required for split screen note
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=ieee,citestyle=authoryear,citetracker=true,ibidtracker=false]{biblatex} % Required for citation
\renewcommand\citesetup{\footnotesize}

\usepackage{hyperref}

%-------------------------------------------------------
% DRAWING FIGURES TIKZ
%-------------------------------------------------------

% tikz
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes,shapes.geometric,calc}
\tikzstyle{startstop} = [rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=1.2cm, minimum height=0.7cm,text centered, draw=black, fill=red!30]
\tikzstyle{io} = [trapezium, trapezium left angle=70, trapezium right angle=110, minimum width=1.2cm, minimum height=0.7cm, text centered, draw=black, fill=blue!30]
\tikzstyle{process} = [rectangle, minimum width=1.2cm, minimum height=0.7cm, text centered, draw=black, fill=orange!30]
\tikzstyle{decision} = [diamond, aspect=1.5, minimum width=0.7cm, minimum height=0.7cm, text centered, text width=1.5cm, draw=black, fill=green!30, execute at begin node={\begin{varwidth}{30em}}, execute at end node={\end{varwidth}}]
\tikzstyle{arrow} = [thick,->,>=stealth]

%-------------------------------------------------------
% DEFFINING AND REDEFINING COMMANDS
%-------------------------------------------------------

\renewcommand{\eqref}[1]{$Eq\ \ref{#1}$}

% citation
\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{firstinits=true, isbn=false, url=false, doi=false, uniquename=init}
\AtEveryCitekey{%
\ifentrytype{article}{
\clearfield{pages}%
\clearfield{volume}%
}{}
}

% font
% \setbeamerfont{footnote}{size=\tiny}

% math underline with color
\newsavebox\MBox
\newcommand\Cunderline[2][red]{{\sbox\MBox{$#2$}%
\rlap{\usebox\MBox}\color{#1}\rule[-1.2\dp\MBox]{\wd\MBox}{0.5pt}}}

% citation
% \setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}{\insertbiblabel}
\DeclareCiteCommand{\sfcite}[\cbx@superscript]%
  {\usebibmacro{cite:init}%
   \let\multicitedelim=\supercitedelim
   \iffieldundef{prenote}{}{\BibliographyWarning{Ignoring prenote argument}}%
   \iffieldundef{postnote}{}{\BibliographyWarning{Ignoring postnote argument}}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \ifciteseen
     {\ifnumequal{\value{page}}{\csuse{cbx@page@\thefield{entrykey}}}
       {}
       {\ifnumequal{\value{framenumber}}{\csuse{cbx@frame@\thefield{entrykey}}}
          {\usebibmacro{sfcite}}
          {}}}
     {\usebibmacro{sfcite}}%
   \usebibmacro{cite:comp}}
  {}
  {\usebibmacro{cite:dump}}

% remove the space in front of the parencite

% reference font
\renewcommand*{\bibfont}{\footnotesize}

\bibliography{literature.bib}

\begin{document}
    network design\parencite{lin2011strategic}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't have your `literature.bib`, so I tested with `\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}` and `sigfridsson`. I could not reproduce the problem then. What version of `biblatex` are you running? (The current version is 3.7.) Note that the linked question is unlikely to help since it is about a vastly different style.

Comment: And I am using biber 2.7

Comment: Mhh, I can't reproduce the problem even with your `.bib` entry. Does the screenshot come from the exact MWE you posted or does it come from a larger document? Can you reproduce the problem with the MWE?

Comment: biblatex version is 3.7

Comment: With your MWE I only get 'Lin and Yang 2011'. The fact that in your screenshot we have 'T.-H. Yang' makes me suspect the screenshot is from the context of a larger document. Please try to isolate the problem from the larger document.

Comment: Yes this comes from the MWE directly. This is really weird because I never came across anything like this before...

Comment: Oh but there are some other unused packages I didn't show in the MWE. You really reminded me here that I should isolate those packages and see which one might cause the trouble.

Comment: I can hardly believe that. When I ran it on my machine I didn't get the 'T.-H.' part (and of course no spurious space). There is nothing in the MWE that should cause the 'T.-H.' to appear. So there must be something else (we don't see) causing it. Do you have any local biblatex `.cfg`s or `.def`s? Can you reproduce the problem with the `article` document class? If so, please change your example to use `article` and show us the whole `.log` file.

Comment: I used article and show the whole article file and the .log file above. This time the -H is gone but the space is still there..

Comment: @GavinLin Please, where can we see the article and its log file?

Comment: Sorry the log file is too large so you can see this at here:https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6GUch7MzERNaHFpRkdzbUhpamM/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @samcarter the log file for article build is provided via google drive link above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The spurious spaces are caused by

```
\AtEveryCitekey{%
\ifentrytype{article}{
\clearfield{pages}%
\clearfield{volume}%
}{}
}
```

You need to protect (some) line ends by `%` so they don't cause spaces. See [What is the use of percent signs (%) at the end of lines?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7453/35864).

With

```
\AtEveryCitekey{%
  \ifentrytype{article}{%
    \clearfield{pages}%
    \clearfield{volume}}
  {}%
}
```

the space should be gone.

Comment: Thank you so much! It did work! I didn't see it coming this way.. I must have somehow changed this when I rearrange my header.tex file. Thank you!

Comment: @moewe Does this indicate that we cannot use inline comments for these macro-definitions?

Comment: @llinfeng Absolutely not, you can use them if you want. Just make sure that there are no spaces before the `%`.

Comment: @moewe, awesome! Thank you for clarifying! I created the trouble by trying to add inline comments for each field/option in the `\AtEveryCitekey`, and spaces were created, exactly, due to the multiple spaces that I put in front of the `%` sign.