# biblatex: is there a command analogous to \ifciteseen but within one page?

Tags: biblatex, conditionals

Biblatex is loaded as

```
\usepackage[style=numeric-comp,hyperref=true]{biblatex}
\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{citetracker=true,sorting=none,firstinits=true}
```

I am looking for an if-command, which would do the same job as `\ifciteseen` does, but only for the current page.

The idea is to test if some source has been cited already on the current page and, depending on the result, change the citation. For instance, if I want to produce a footnote only upon the first citation **on the current page**, I could do

```
\ifciteseenONTHISPAGE
{% yes, do nothing
 }
{% no, do smth
 \noexpand\footnote[\thefield{labelnumber}]{%
 \fullcite{\thefield{entrykey}}\addperiod}}}}
```

I am aware of `\iffirstonpage` and `\ifsamepage` but cannot figure out if they can be of any help here and how.

Comment: Related newer question with a slightly more sophisticated answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/71526/35864.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The counter `instcount` uniquely identifies a citation or item in the bibliography/list of shorthands. The test `\ifsamepage{<inst1>}{<inst2>}{<true>}{<false>}` expands `<true>` if the two citations/items identified by the `instcount` values `<inst1>` and `<inst2>` are found on the same page.

In your test we need to compare the current value (`\value{instcount}`) with the value of `instcount` the last time the current entry was cited. In general this is not the value of `instcount` in the last citation (i.e. `\value{instcount}-1`). AFAIK you'll have to track the last `instcount` value for each entry with some additional code.

The example below demonstrates how this can be done using a citation format considered in a [previous post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/20637/4483). It relies on some commands from `etoolbox` and requires additional passes to get the tests right.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[style=numeric-comp,citetracker=true,pagetracker=true,sorting=none]{biblatex}

\makeatletter
%---------------------------------------------------------------
% Essentially verbatim from Joseph Wright (except for refinements to \ifciteseen test)
% http://www.texdev.net/2010/03/08/biblatex-numbered-citations-as-footnotes/

\DeclareCiteCommand{\superfootcite}[\cbx@superscript]
  {\usebibmacro{cite:init}%
   \let\multicitedelim=\supercitedelim
   \iffieldundef{prenote}
     {}
     {\BibliographyWarning{Ignoring prenote argument}}%
   \iffieldundef{postnote}
     {}
     {\BibliographyWarning{Ignoring postnote argument}}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cite:superfoot}%
   \usebibmacro{cite:comp}}
  {}
  {\usebibmacro{cite:dump}}

\newbibmacro*{cite:superfoot}{%
  \xdef\cbx@citekey{\thefield{entrykey}}%
  \ifciteseen
    {}
    {\csnumgdef{cbx@instcount\cbx@citekey}{-100}}%
  \ifsamepage{\value{instcount}}{\number\csuse{cbx@instcount\cbx@citekey}}
    {}
    {\xappto\cbx@citehook{%
       \noexpand\footnotetext[\thefield{labelnumber}]{%
         \fullcite{\thefield{entrykey}}\addperiod}}}%
  \csnumgdef{cbx@instcount\cbx@citekey}{\value{instcount}}}

\newrobustcmd{\cbx@superscript}[1]{%
  \mkbibsuperscript{#1}%
  \cbx@citehook
  \global\let\cbx@citehook=\empty}
\let\cbx@citehook=\empty

%---------------------------------------------------------------
\makeatother

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Title}
\null\vfill\noindent
First citation.\superfootcite{bertram}
First citation.\superfootcite{companion}
Some recurrent citations on same page.\superfootcite{bertram,companion,augustine}
\chapter{Title}
\null\vfill\noindent
Recurrent citation on different page.\superfootcite{companion}
Recurrent on different page and first citations.\superfootcite{augustine,cicero}
Recurrent citation on same page.\superfootcite{companion}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Here are the citations from the first page:

[image]

And from the second:

[image]

Comment: Great, thanks! I've combined the code above with some other code of yours (and Joseph, of course)  http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20787/biblatex-cite-with-footnote-only-once-with-use-of-brackets and some cosmetic changes from my side to achieve exactly what I needed. I see a lot of questions connected to footnote citation style. Do you consider writing a package, which would incorporate different modifications of it and would allow switching between different styles in a flexible way?

Comment: @amorua Perhaps eventually, unless Joseph prefers to write one himself or someone else beats me to it. Ideally I'd like to see some adaptation of code from `manyfoot`, but I don't have time to look into that right now.

Comment: Your solution worked perfectly for me. I have one question though. Do you think it is possible to have the footnotes with cites sorted? To explain what I mean, let's look at your example: imagine on page 2 you would first cite Augustine [3] and only then Goosens [2]. Then the footnotes would be in the following order: [3], then [2] and then [4]. Is it possible to have them sorted: although the citation order is 3,2,4, the footnotes would first list 2, then 3 and 4? If you think it is something that can be done, I would like to post a new question.

Comment: @amorua I finally got around to solving this problem [over here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/71526/4483). It is suited mainly for documents where the list of shorthands and bibliography appear on new pages, though.

Answer (score 3):

This is a slightly modified version of Audrey's approach above

```
\AtEveryCitekey{%
  \ifcsundef{cbx@instcount@curr@\the\c@refsection @\thefield{entrykey}}
    {\csnumgdef{cbx@instcount@curr@\the\c@refsection @\thefield{entrykey}}{0}}
    {}%
  \csnumgdef{cbx@instcount@last@\the\c@refsection @\thefield{entrykey}}{%
    \csuse{cbx@instcount@curr@\the\c@refsection @\thefield{entrykey}}}%
  \csnumgdef{cbx@instcount@curr@\the\c@refsection @\thefield{entrykey}}{\value{instcount}}}

\def\iflastciteonsamepage{%
  \ifsamepage
    {\number\csuse{cbx@instcount@curr@\the\c@refsection @\thefield{entrykey}}}
    {\number\csuse{cbx@instcount@last@\the\c@refsection @\thefield{entrykey}}}}
```

Where `\iflastciteonsamepage` checks if the last citation of the current work was on the same page (as detected by `\ifsamepage`).

Please be aware that this test is not guaranteed to work in all circumstances, I have tested it for some (relatively common) cases, but there might well be cases where this breaks down horribly. Thanks to Audrey to pointing this out in the comments.

Audrey's MWE then becomes

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[style=numeric-comp,citetracker=true,pagetracker=true,sorting=none]{biblatex}

\makeatletter
%---------------------------------------------------------------
% Essentially verbatim from Joseph Wright (except for refinements to \ifciteseen test)
% http://www.texdev.net/2010/03/08/biblatex-numbered-citations-as-footnotes/

\DeclareCiteCommand{\superfootcite}[\cbx@superscript]
  {\usebibmacro{cite:init}%
   \let\multicitedelim=\supercitedelim
   \iffieldundef{prenote}
     {}
     {\BibliographyWarning{Ignoring prenote argument}}%
   \iffieldundef{postnote}
     {}
     {\BibliographyWarning{Ignoring postnote argument}}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cite:superfoot}%
   \usebibmacro{cite:comp}}
  {}
  {\usebibmacro{cite:dump}}

\AtEveryCitekey{%
  \ifcsundef{cbx@instcount@curr@\the\c@refsection @\thefield{entrykey}}
    {\csnumgdef{cbx@instcount@curr@\the\c@refsection @\thefield{entrykey}}{0}}
    {}%
  \csnumgdef{cbx@instcount@last@\the\c@refsection @\thefield{entrykey}}{%
    \csuse{cbx@instcount@curr@\the\c@refsection @\thefield{entrykey}}}%
  \csnumgdef{cbx@instcount@curr@\the\c@refsection @\thefield{entrykey}}{\value{instcount}}}

\def\iflastciteonsamepage{%
  \ifsamepage
    {\number\csuse{cbx@instcount@curr@\the\c@refsection @\thefield{entrykey}}}
    {\number\csuse{cbx@instcount@last@\the\c@refsection @\thefield{entrykey}}}}

\newbibmacro*{cite:superfoot}{% 
  \iflastciteonsamepage   
    {}
    {\xappto\cbx@citehook{%
       \noexpand\footnotetext[\thefield{labelnumber}]{%
         \fullcite{\thefield{entrykey}}\addperiod}}}}

\newrobustcmd{\cbx@superscript}[1]{%
  \mkbibsuperscript{#1}%
  \cbx@citehook
  \global\let\cbx@citehook=\empty}
\let\cbx@citehook=\empty
%---------------------------------------------------------------
\makeatother

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Title}
\null\vfill\noindent
First citation.\superfootcite{bertram}
First citation.\superfootcite{companion}
Some recurrent citations on same page.\superfootcite{bertram,companion,augustine}
\chapter{Title}
\null\vfill\noindent
Recurrent citation on different page.\superfootcite{companion}
Recurrent on different page and first citations.\superfootcite{augustine,cicero}
Recurrent citation on same page.\superfootcite{companion}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

For the first page

[image: first page of MWE]

and for the second page

[image: second page of MWE]

---

While this version is more robust in some aspects, it is still not guaranteed to work in all circumstances.

Comment: I didn't intend this test to be user-level. It is specific to the special 1:1 correspondence between a single citation and a footnote in the OP's desired style. There are likely unanticipated results with initializing in `\AtDataInput`. I suspect this won't work with numeric styles under reference sections or multiple sorting schemes.

Comment: @Audrey Ah, thanks, I didn't think of that. Is there another hook one could use? Of course I could just move the initialisation into the `\AtEveryCitekey` with an `\ifciteseen`, I presume ...

Comment: @Audrey Thank you again for your comment. Would you mind having a look at my second suggestion that seems to play well with `refsection`s at least?

Comment: This might work is some settings, but I know the strategy isn't good enough as a general test. That is why I embedded the test into the OP's citation style and didn't make the it directly accessible.

Comment: @Audrey OK, thank you very much again. I will add a more prominent warning then. If you happen to stumble across a case where this doesn't work or have any further explanations as to what could go wrong, I would be really interested.

Answer (score 1):

You should try (with `pagetracker` activated) something like this (works by me when I use it in my custom style) :

```
\ifciteseen{%
    \ifsamepage{\value{instcount}}{\value{instcount}-1}{Do nothing}
    {Print the reference}}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not do the trick. Actually, if I have something like `\cite{a1} text \cite{a2} text \cite{a3}` on the same page, then the conditional above will give `false` only for `a1` and `true` for `a2` and `a3`. Whereas `a2` and `a3` are certainly "new citations". Is there any counter "for a given citation key", just like `instcount` is for all citations?