# Improve footnotes citation with Biblatex

Tags: biblatex, footnotes, citing

While using `biblatex` I want to display the full citations in footnotes, and in the text the following format `author (year)^citation number`. For now I am using as it is in the MWE. Is there a better way to achieve the same format and also for the citations for the same book, use the same number, i.e., use just `1` in the `rappaport:2002` instead of `1` and `3`?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[backend=biber,style=footnote-dw]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\usepackage{xparse}
\DeclareDocumentCommand{\myfootcite}{ O{} O{} m }{\citeauthor*[#1][]{#3}~(\citedate[][]{#3})\cite[][#2]{#3}}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{rappaport:2002,
    title={Wireless Communications: Principles and Practice},
    author={Theodore S.~Rappaport},
    publisher={Prentice Hall},
  month=jan,
    year=2002,
  isdn={978-0130422323},
  edition=2,
}

@book{goldsmith:2004,
    title={Wireless Communications},
    author={Andrea Goldsmith},
    publisher={Stanford University},
    year=2004,
    url={http://www.cs.ucdavis.edu/~liu/289I/Material/book-goldsmith.pdf},
    urldate={2013-06},
}
\end{filecontents*}


\begin{document}
Test1~\myfootcite[p.~165][]{rappaport:2002}
\par
Test2~\myfootcite[p.~230][]{goldsmith:2004}
\par
Test3~\myfootcite[][]{rappaport:2002}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This problem has been covered in a [previous post](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/82670). The solution there can be adapted to your case by replacing `\cite` with the new `\superfootcite`. The `biblatex-dw` styles do all kinds of tracking, so you'll at least have to add `\citetrackerfalse` to the first (`<precode>`) argument in the definition of `\superfootcite`.

Comment: @Audrey I will check the solution later. Thanks for pointing out the post. I only use `biblatex-dw` because of the `footnote-dw`, it can be replaced by any other style, if I can still have references in footnotes. I saw in the post that pages are cited as `\superfootcite[<page number>]{<citekey>}`. How would tables and figures be cited?

Comment: The usual format is `\cite[<prenote>][<postnote>]{<keys>}`. Page references go in `<postnote>`. So can references to tables or figures. In `<prenote>` prefixes like "e.g." or "cf." are used. `\superfootcite` checks for recurrent `\strfield{postnote}`+`entrykey` combinations. The solution could be extended to `prenote`. BTW: Use of `xparse` isn't necessary for multi-pass citation commands. `\textcite` in the more recent verbose styles exploits the citation command interface. Under this approach you can access and move trailing punctuation and compress citation labels.

Comment: @Audrey I tested the solution in the other post, but I want `prenotes` and `postnotes` to be added in the main text rather than in the bibliography itself, like in my MWE.

Comment: Well, you're actually using only the `prenote` argument in the MWE. The example passes page references to `prenote` when typically they go in the `postnote`. Your desired format is unclear, which is why I've been commenting this whole time instead of simply answering. Are you wanting output like: `<prenote> <name label> (<year label>, <postnote>)^<footnote mark>`?

Comment: @Audrey Yes, something like that. Where `<prenote>` and `<postnote>` are optional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `\textcite` command implemented in `footnote-dw` does almost what you want if we combine it with [Multiply cited reference in footnotes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/82670/35864), it doesn't print the year and the positions of the pre- and postnotes are different. Fortunately though, with a bit of help from `authoryear.cbx` we can implement your desired output.

This is from `authoryear.cbx` (with a few modifications)

```
\newbool{cbx:parens}

\newbibmacro*{ay:textcite}{%
  \printnames{labelname}%
  \setunit{%
    \global\booltrue{cbx:parens}%
    \addspace\bibopenparen}%
   \printdate}

\newbibmacro*{ay:textcite:postnote}{%
  \iffieldundef{postnote}
    {\ifbool{cbx:parens}
       {\bibcloseparen}
       {}}
    {\ifbool{cbx:parens}
       {\setunit{\postnotedelim}}
       {\setunit{\addspace\bibopenparen}}%
     \printfield{postnote}\bibcloseparen}}
```

Then

```
\DeclareCiteCommand{\etextcite}[\footnotecheck\cbx@textcite\superfootcite]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}%
   \gdef\cbx@savedkeys{}}
  {\usebibmacro{ay:textcite}%
   \ifciteseen
     {\global\boolfalse{cbx:textcitefull}}
     {\global\booltrue{cbx:textcitefull}}%
   \xappto\cbx@savedkeys{\thefield{entrykey},}}
  {\multinamedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{ay:textcite:postnote}%
   \protected@xappto\cbx@savedcites{{\cbx@savedkeys}}}
```

is a modification of `\textcite` in `footnote-dw.cbx`.

Finally, we need [Audrey's](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/4483/audrey) `\superfullcite` from [Multiply cited reference in footnotes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/82750/35864).

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=footnote-dw]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\newbool{cbx:parens}

\newbibmacro*{ay:textcite}{%
  \printnames{labelname}%
  \setunit{%
    \global\booltrue{cbx:parens}%
    \addspace\bibopenparen}%
   \printdate}

\newbibmacro*{ay:textcite:postnote}{%
  \iffieldundef{postnote}
    {\ifbool{cbx:parens}
       {\bibcloseparen}
       {}}
    {\ifbool{cbx:parens}
       {\setunit{\postnotedelim}}
       {\setunit{\addspace\bibopenparen}}%
     \printfield{postnote}\bibcloseparen}}

\makeatletter
\DeclareCiteCommand{\etextcite}[\footnotecheck\cbx@textcite\superfootcite]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}%
   \gdef\cbx@savedkeys{}}
  {\usebibmacro{ay:textcite}%
   \ifciteseen
     {\global\boolfalse{cbx:textcitefull}}
     {\global\booltrue{cbx:textcitefull}}%
   \xappto\cbx@savedkeys{\thefield{entrykey},}}
  {\multinamedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{ay:textcite:postnote}%
   \protected@xappto\cbx@savedcites{{\cbx@savedkeys}}}


\DeclareCiteCommand{\superfootcite}[\cbx@wrap]
  {\gdef\cbx@keys{}\citetrackerfalse}
  {\xappto\cbx@keys{\thefield{entrykey},}}
  {}
  {\ifcsundef{cbx@lastin@\cbx@keys @\strfield{postnote}}
     {\csnumgdef{cbx@lastin@\cbx@keys @\strfield{postnote}}{-1}}{}%
   \ifsamepage{\value{instcount}}{\csuse{cbx@lastin@\cbx@keys @\strfield{postnote}}}
     {\footnotemark[\csuse{cbx@lastfn@\cbx@keys @\strfield{postnote}}]}
     {\xappto\cbx@cite{\noexpand\footcite%
        [\thefield{prenote}][\thefield{postnote}]{\cbx@keys}%
        \csnumgdef{cbx@lastfn@\cbx@keys @\strfield{postnote}}{\value{\@mpfn}}%
        \csnumgdef{cbx@lastin@\cbx@keys @\strfield{postnote}}{\value{instcount}}}}}

\newrobustcmd{\cbx@wrap}[1]{#1\cbx@cite\gdef\cbx@cite{}}
\def\cbx@cite{}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
Lorem \etextcite[cf.][12]{sigfridsson} ipsum \etextcite{geer}
dolor \etextcite{sigfridsson} sit \etextcite{geer} amet \etextcite{wilde}.
\end{document}
```

[image: example output]

Comment: Thank you very much! It is ways good to learn something every day :).