# Highlight an author in bibliography using biblatex allowing bibliography style to format it

Tags: biblatex, biber

I am writing my thesis and I want to highlight my name in the publications using the `\fullcite{}` while keeping the main bibliography untouched (if not possible, the name can also be highlighted there). I tried the approaches in :

- [Make specific author bold using biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73136/make-specific-author-bold-using-biblatex)
- [Make one author's name bold every time it shows up in the bibliography](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33330/make-one-authors-name-bold-every-time-it-shows-up-in-the-bibliography)

But I was not able to put it work. Thus I defined a command:

```
% Show me as author
%\newcommand*{\showme}[1]{\textbf{#1}}
\newcommand*{\showme}[1]{\mkbibbold{#1}}
```

To be used inside my biblio.bib. It seem to work. But them I noticed that the entry is not formated as the other authors' name. It was easy to see because I am using `ieee` style.

```
@incollection{Silva:2014a,
  title={Radio Resource Management for Device-to-Device Communications in Long Term Evolution Networks},
  author={\showme{Carlos F. M. Silva} and Jos\'{e} Mairton B. Silva Jr. and Tarcisio F. Maciel},
  booktitle={Resource Allocation and {MIMO} for {4G} and Beyond},
  publisher={Springer Science+Business Media},
  year=2014,
  address={New York, USA},
  editor={Francisco Rodrigo Porto Cavalcanti},
  pages={105-156},
  doi={10.1007/978-1-4614-8057-0_3},
  isbn={978-1-4614-8056-3},
}
```

Which gives:

> **Carlos F. M. Silva**, J. M. B. S. Jr., and T. F. Maciel, “Radio resource management for device-to-device communications in long term
>   evolution networks”, in Resource Allocation and MIMO for 4G and
>   Beyond, F. R. P. Cavalcanti, Ed., New York, USA: Springer
>   Science+Business Media, 2014, pp. 105–156, isbn: 978-1-4614-8056-3.
>   doi:
>   10.1007/978-1-4614-8057-0_3

As it can be seen, my first name appears full, while the correct entry would be **C. F. M. Silva**. I know this happens because anything inside `{}` is not formated by the bibliography style.

So my question is: how can I define such a command to let the bibliography style to format my name and put it on bold if a flag is on, i.e., `\ifshowme=1`. The MWE is below.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=ieee]{biblatex}

% Show me as author
%\newcommand*{\showme}[1]{\textbf{#1}}
\newcommand*{\showme}[1]{\mkbibbold{#1}}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{biblio.bib}
  @incollection{Silva:2014a,
      title={Radio Resource Management for Device-to-Device Communications in Long Term Evolution Networks},
      author={\showme{Carlos F. M. Silva} and Jos\'{e} Mairton B. Silva Jr. and Tarcisio F. Maciel},
      booktitle={Resource Allocation and {MIMO} for {4G} and Beyond},
      publisher={Springer Science+Business Media},
      year=2014,
      address={New York, USA},
      editor={Francisco Rodrigo Porto Cavalcanti},
      pages={105-156},
      doi={10.1007/978-1-4614-8057-0_3},
      isbn={978-1-4614-8056-3},
    }
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{biblio.bib}

\begin{document}

\fullcite{Silva:2014a}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: You should not alter the `author` list by wrapping certain names in macros, that destroys Biber's ability to parse them correctly, as you found out. My go-to solution is [Make specific author bold using biblatex](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73136/make-specific-author-bold-using-biblatex), you will have to try matching for `\forcsvlist{\listadd\boldnames}
  {{Silva, C\bibinitperiod\bibinitdelim F\bibinitperiod\bibinitdelim M\bibinitperiod}}` The modern solution would check against the `hash` which in your case is `5e1df516fe8816ee66169b8616522816`.

Comment: Can you post a solution.  Also I have my name written in different forms, how can I know this biblatex macros that I can use, I mean the \bibinitperiod and friends?

Comment: You have to have a look at the `.bbl` file. I will post a `hash` solution and explain how to extract the information from the `.bbl`.

Comment: There you are. If you can spare the time you might want to have a look at my recent answer to [an ancient question of yours](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/123017/35864) I attempted to get it off the unanswered list, let me know what you think.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Edit** Continuing updates for this methods are posted to https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/416416/35864.

The following solution automatically extracts the hashes for the given names.  Everything else is based on the bit of the answer below.

*Warning!* The code will write a `.bib` file called `<your TeX file/\jobname>-boldnames.bib`, if it exists, it will be overwritten. You can change the name of that file by adjusting the value of `\hlblx@bibfile@name`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=numeric]{biblatex}

\makeatletter
\def\hlblx@bibfile@name{\jobname -boldnames.bib}
\newwrite\hlblx@bibfile
\immediate\openout\hlblx@bibfile=\hlblx@bibfile@name
\newcounter{hlblx@name}
\setcounter{hlblx@name}{0}
\newcommand*{\hlblx@writenametobib}[1]{%
  \stepcounter{hlblx@name}%
  \edef\hlblx@tmp@nocite{%
    \noexpand\AfterPreamble{%
      \noexpand\setbox0\noexpand\vbox{%
        \noexpand\hlblx@getmethehash{hlblx@name@\the\value{hlblx@name}}}}%
  }%
  \hlblx@tmp@nocite
  \immediate\write\hlblx@bibfile{%
    @misc{hlblx@name@\the\value{hlblx@name}, author = {\unexpanded{#1}}, %
          options = {dataonly=true},}%
  }%
}

\AtEndDocument{%
  \closeout\hlblx@bibfile}

\addbibresource{\hlblx@bibfile@name}

\newcommand*{\hlbxl@boldhashes}{}
\DeclareNameFormat{hlblx@hashextract}{%
  \xifinlist{\thefield{hash}}{\hlbxl@boldhashes}
    {}
    {\listxadd{\hlbxl@boldhashes}{\thefield{fullhash}}}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\hlblx@getmethehash}
  {}
  {\printnames[hlblx@hashextract][1-999]{author}}
  {}
  {}

\newcommand*{\addboldname}{\forcsvlist\hlblx@writenametobib}
\newcommand*{\resetboldnames}{\def\hlbxl@boldhashes{}}

\newcommand*{\mkboldifhashinlist}[1]{%
  \xifinlist{\thefield{hash}}{\hlbxl@boldhashes}
    {\mkbibbold{#1}}
    {#1}}
\makeatother

\DeclareNameWrapperFormat{boldifhashinlist}{%
  \renewcommand*{\mkbibcompletename}{\mkboldifhashinlist}%
  #1}

\DeclareNameWrapperAlias{sortname}{default}
\DeclareNameWrapperAlias{default}{boldifhashinlist}


\addboldname{{Silva, Carlos F. M.}}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@incollection{Silva:2014a,
  title     = {Radio Resource Management for Device-to-Device
               Communications in Long Term Evolution Networks},
  author    = {Carlos F. M. Silva and Silva, Jr., Jos\'{e} Mairton B.
               and Tarcisio F. Maciel},
  booktitle = {Resource Allocation and {MIMO} for {4G} and Beyond},
  publisher = {Springer Science+Business Media},
  year      = 2014,
  address   = {New York, USA},
  editor    = {Francisco Rodrigo Porto Cavalcanti},
  pages     = {105-156},
  doi       = {10.1007/978-1-4614-8057-0_3},
  isbn      = {978-1-4614-8056-3},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\fullcite{Silva:2014a}

\resetboldnames\addboldname{{Silva, Jr., Jos\'{e} Mairton B.}}\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

---

We can use [Audrey](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/4483/audrey)'s approach to [Make specific author bold using biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/73136/35864), but instead of string comparison we use the name hash produced by Biber.

```
\newcommand*{\boldnames}{}
\newcommand*{\mkboldifhashinlist}[1]{%
  \xifinlist{\thefield{hash}}{\boldnames}
    {\mkbibbold{#1}}
    {#1}}

\DeclareNameWrapperFormat{boldifhashinlist}{%
  \renewcommand*{\mkbibcompletename}{\mkboldifhashinlist}%
  #1}

\DeclareNameWrapperAlias{sortname}{default}
\DeclareNameWrapperAlias{default}{boldifhashinlist}
```

You can find out the `hash` values for your name (and its versions) by looking at the `.bbl` file produced by Biber, it will contain information for a cited entry like this

```
\entry{Silva:2014a}{incollection}{}
  \name{author}{3}{}{%
    {{hash=894de27062ab25d43f1d7b50fd923256}{%
       family={Silva},
       familyi={S\bibinitperiod},
       given={Carlos\bibnamedelimb F.\bibnamedelimi M.},
       giveni={C\bibinitperiod\bibinitdelim F\bibinitperiod\bibinitdelim M\bibinitperiod}}}%
    {{hash=cc273ec4593222cb35c353d3f073214e}{%
       family={Silva},
       familyi={S\bibinitperiod},
       given={José\bibnamedelimb Mairton\bibnamedelima B.},
       giveni={J\bibinitperiod\bibinitdelim M\bibinitperiod\bibinitdelim B\bibinitperiod},
       suffix={Jr.},
       suffixi={J\bibinitperiod}}}%
    {{hash=1f31fc59b1a438cdb6e7efa3f16611fe}{%
       family={Maciel},
       familyi={M\bibinitperiod},
       given={Tarcisio\bibnamedelima F.},
       giveni={T\bibinitperiod\bibinitdelim F\bibinitperiod}}}%
  }
  \name{editor}{1}{}{%
    {{hash=3ac5e392f4edfbddb80549d1ccca0d11}{%
       family={Cavalcanti},
       familyi={C\bibinitperiod},
       given={Francisco\bibnamedelimb Rodrigo\bibnamedelima Porto},
       giveni={F\bibinitperiod\bibinitdelim R\bibinitperiod\bibinitdelim P\bibinitperiod}}}%
  }
  \list{location}{1}{%
    {New York, USA}%
  }
  \list{publisher}{1}{%
    {Springer Science+Business Media}%
  }
  \strng{namehash}{b4c654eecf5e554d731ed21594f20b31}
  \strng{fullhash}{b4c654eecf5e554d731ed21594f20b31}
  \strng{bibnamehash}{b4c654eecf5e554d731ed21594f20b31}
  \strng{authorbibnamehash}{b4c654eecf5e554d731ed21594f20b31}
  \strng{authornamehash}{b4c654eecf5e554d731ed21594f20b31}
  \strng{authorfullhash}{b4c654eecf5e554d731ed21594f20b31}
  \strng{editorbibnamehash}{3ac5e392f4edfbddb80549d1ccca0d11}
  \strng{editornamehash}{3ac5e392f4edfbddb80549d1ccca0d11}
  \strng{editorfullhash}{3ac5e392f4edfbddb80549d1ccca0d11}
  \field{sortinit}{S}
  \field{sortinithash}{c319cff79d99c853d775f88277d4e45f}
  \field{labelnamesource}{author}
  \field{labeltitlesource}{title}
  \field{booktitle}{Resource Allocation and {MIMO} for {4G} and Beyond}
  \field{isbn}{978-1-4614-8056-3}
  \field{title}{Radio Resource Management for Device-to-Device Communications in Long Term Evolution Networks}
  \field{year}{2014}
  \field{pages}{105\bibrangedash 156}
  \range{pages}{52}
  \verb{doi}
  \verb 10.1007/978-1-4614-8057-0_3
  \endverb
\endentry
```

The hash for the relevant name is shown right before the name, for C. F. M. Silva is `894de27062ab25d43f1d7b50fd923256`, for J. M. B Silva Jr. it is `cc273ec4593222cb35c353d3f073214e`. (Note that the value of this hash may change between Biber version: Check that the names highlight correctly after an update.)

Since the `hash` is different for different name inputs (the `hash` for "Donald E. Knuth" will not equal the one for "D. E. Knuth" or "Donald Knuth")
you will have to find the correct hash for all the variants you use of your name.

With the help of

```
\newcommand*{\detokenizelistadd}[2]{%
  \listeadd#1{\detokenize{#2}}}
```

you can then add a list of hashes to the `\boldnames` macro

```
\forcsvlist{\detokenizelistadd\boldnames}
  {{894de27062ab25d43f1d7b50fd923256}}
```

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=numeric]{biblatex}

\newcommand*{\boldnames}{}
\newcommand*{\mkboldifhashinlist}[1]{%
  \xifinlist{\thefield{hash}}{\boldnames}
    {\mkbibbold{#1}}
    {#1}}

\DeclareNameWrapperFormat{boldifhashinlist}{%
  \renewcommand*{\mkbibcompletename}{\mkboldifhashinlist}%
  #1}

\DeclareNameWrapperAlias{sortname}{default}
\DeclareNameWrapperAlias{default}{boldifhashinlist}


\newcommand*{\detokenizelistadd}[2]{%
  \listeadd#1{\detokenize{#2}}}

\renewcommand*{\boldnames}{}
\forcsvlist{\detokenizelistadd\boldnames}
  {{894de27062ab25d43f1d7b50fd923256}}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@incollection{Silva:2014a,
  title     = {Radio Resource Management for Device-to-Device
               Communications in Long Term Evolution Networks},
  author    = {Carlos F. M. Silva and Silva, Jr., Jos\'{e} Mairton B.
               and Tarcisio F. Maciel},
  booktitle = {Resource Allocation and {MIMO} for {4G} and Beyond},
  publisher = {Springer Science+Business Media},
  year      = 2014,
  address   = {New York, USA},
  editor    = {Francisco Rodrigo Porto Cavalcanti},
  pages     = {105-156},
  doi       = {10.1007/978-1-4614-8057-0_3},
  isbn      = {978-1-4614-8056-3},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\fullcite{Silva:2014a}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Output]

*The answer has been updated to reflect the changes needed for `biblatex` >= 3.3 (see [`biblatex` 3.3 name formatting](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/299036/35864)). All mentions of `last` in name macros are now `family` and `first` becomes `given`. Refer to the edit history for the pre-3.3 code.*

*edited* to use a more elegant version to format complete names. `\DeclareNameWrapperFormat` and `\mkbibcompletename` are only available in `biblatex` v3.12 (2018-10-30) and v3.13 (2019-08-17), respectively. Please refer to the edit history if you are using an older version of `biblatex`.

Comment: In my MWE above I swithced the style to `numeric` for some reason, but you will find that it works with `ieee` just as well. You will also find that I have entered the second name as `Silva, Jr., Jos\'{e} Mairton B.`, if it is entered as `Jos\'{e} Mairton B. Silva Jr.` Biber will think the last name is "Jr." and the first name is "Jos\'{e} Mairton B. Silva" which is obviously nonsense.

Comment: Alternative you can use the second solution in Audrey's post with `\boldname{Silva}{Carlos F.~M.}{C.~F.~M.}` (though that will break down if you leave out any initials in any of your `.bib` entries).

Comment: The MWE no longer seems to work in biblatex 3.4/ biber 2.5, my most recent TeX-dist upgrade seems to have broken this. At least with these I see no bold face in the MWE at all. Can anyone else confirm this or, preferably, has a work-around?

Comment: My issues seems to have been the ordering of firstname-lastname and that name:first-last and name:last-first have been renamed. With `\xpretobibmacro{name:family-given}{\begingroup\usebibmacro{name:bold}{#1}{#2}}{}{}
\xapptobibmacro{name:family-given}{\endgroup}{}{}
\xpretobibmacro{name:given-family}{\begingroup\usebibmacro{name:bold}{#1}{#2}}{}{}
\xapptobibmacro{name:given-family}{\endgroup}{}{}` I seem to catch both variants and everything seems to work.

Comment: @bjoseru Indeed, the changes in 3.3 require those little changes, I have edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: This doesnt work for me for some reason when I implement this into a template, so in other words the MWE works, but not when I plug it into the actual document which uses a cls file. Any suggestions as to how to troubleshoot? THere are no error/warning messages in the log files. Oh and yes I have changed the hash accordingly..

Comment: @posdef Maybe you are using a different (custom?) name format? The solution should cover the basic name formats of the standard styles (and many contributed styles), but if your actual document does other things to the name format that might interfere. I suggest you try to turn your document where things don't work into an MWE (https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864 and https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864) and ask a new question about it. What bibliography style are you using? Do you have a custom name format?

Comment: @moewe I dont have a custom name format, as far as I know.. Hopefully this line from the cls file should answer your questions about style: `\RequirePackage[backend=biber,style=apa,alldates=year,sorting=none,doi=false]{biblatex}`

Comment: @moewe Turns out `style=apa` breaks this example, because it uses its own fields for names

Comment: @posdef Yup, that would explain it. Maybe https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/253388/35864 can help you.