# Biblatex always show a specific author

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

I am looking for a way to always list one specific author in references with many authors, when the number of authors to show is limited and abbreviated by et al.

For example

```
These are the relevant papers:
\fullcite{paper1}
\fullcite{paper2}
```

should result in

```
These are the relevant papers:
Author, A., ..., Alwaysthisauthor, X., ..., et al. 
Buthor, B., ..., Alwaysthisauthor, X., ..., et al.
```

As requested a minimal example is below:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[backend=biber,natbib]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
  @INPROCEEDINGS{2001AIPC..569..163C,
   author = {{Cheshkov}, S. and {Tajima}, T. and {Chiu}, C. and {Breitling}, F. },
    title = "{Emittance control in Laser Wakefield Accelerator}",
booktitle = {American Institute of Physics Conference Series},
     year = 2001,
   volume = 569,
    month = may,
    pages = {163-176},
}

@ARTICLE{2001RScI...72.1339B,
   author = {{Breitling}, F. and {Weigel}, R.~S. and {Downer}, M.~C. and
    {Tajima}, T.},
    title = "{Laser pointing stabilization and control in the 
        submicroradian regime with neural networks}",
  journal = {Review of Scientific Instruments},
     year = 2001,
    month = feb,
   volume = 72,
    pages = {1339-1342},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Results in

> References
>
> 1. F. Breitling et al. “Laser pointing stabilization and control in the 
>      submicro-radian regime with neural networks”. In: Review of Scientific 
>      Instruments 72 (Feb. 2001), pp. 1339–1342.
> 2. S. Cheshkov et al. “Emittance control in Laser Wakefield Accelerator”.
>      In: American Institute of Physics Conference Series. Vol. 569. May 2001,
>      pp. 163–176.

But I need the name Breitling to always appear explicitly also if the author list is truncated with et al.

Comment: Does [Excluding one certain author from et al.](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/297562/35864) look like what you are after? You probably will not be able to get the code from the answer working because of the changes in version 3.3, but if that is what you are looking for I can try and adapt the code for versions >=3.3.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: Why are you encasing all surnames in curly braces? AFAICT, it adds nothing but code clutter.

Comment: @Mico This is the way I retrieve the bibtex entries from ADS (see [example](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/cgi-bin/nph-bib_query?bibcode=2001AIPC..569..163C&data_type=BIBTEX&db_key=PHY&nocookieset=1)). I don't know in which situations this is necessary.

Comment: @moewe Yes, this seems to be my question. However the title seem misleading since it is more about including than excluding authors. Should we change the title accordingly? If you could update the answer as necessary that would be great!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following is adapted for `biblatex` >= 3.3 from my answer to [Excluding one certain author from [et al.]](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/297562/35864).

In order to make this solution work you will need the hash of your name, see [Highlight an author in bibliography using biblatex allowing bibliography style to format it](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/274436/35864) for details on how to retrieve the hash for specific names from the `.bbl` file.

If you wrap your name into braces, the hash for `F. {Breitling}`/`{Breitling}, F.` is `3f71afbcde39f096d711d45fa2c17bc7`.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=authoryear, backend=biber, maxnames=999]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@INPROCEEDINGS{cheshkov,
   author = {{Cheshkov}, S. and {Tajima}, T. and {Chiu}, C. and {Breitling}, F. },
    title = "{Emittance control in Laser Wakefield Accelerator}",
booktitle = {American Institute of Physics Conference Series},
     year = 2001,
   volume = 569,
    month = may,
    pages = {163-176},
}
@ARTICLE{breitling,
   author = {{Breitling}, F. and {Weigel}, R.~S. and {Downer}, M.~C. and
    {Tajima}, T.},
    title = "{Laser pointing stabilization and control in the 
        submicroradian regime with neural networks}",
  journal = {Review of Scientific Instruments},
     year = 2001,
    month = feb,
   volume = 72,
    pages = {1339-1342},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\newcounter{namesnotimportant}
\newtoggle{ellipsis}

\makeatletter
\newbibmacro*{name:etal:delim}[1]{%
  \ifnumgreater{\value{listcount}}{\value{liststart}}
    {\ifboolexpr{
       test {\ifnumless{\value{listcount}}{\value{liststop}}}
       or
       test \ifmorenames
       or test {\ifnumcomp{\value{namesnotimportant}}{>}{0}}
     }
       {\printdelim{multinamedelim}}
       {\lbx@finalnamedelim{#1}}}
    {}}
\makeatother

\DeclareNameFormat{given-family-etal}{%
  \letbibmacro{name:delim}{name:etal:delim}%
  \ifnumcomp{\value{listcount}}{=}{1}
    {\setcounter{namesnotimportant}{0}%
     \global\toggletrue{ellipsis}}
    {}%
  \ifboolexpr{test {\ifnumcomp{\value{listcount}}{=}{1}}
              or test {\ifnumcomp{\value{listtotal}}{=}{2}}}
    {\ifgiveninits
      {\usebibmacro{name:given-family}
         {\namepartfamily}
         {\namepartgiveni}
         {\namepartprefix}
         {\namepartsuffix}}
      {\usebibmacro{name:given-family}
         {\namepartfamily}
         {\namepartgiven}
         {\namepartprefix}
         {\namepartsuffix}}}%
    {\iffieldequalstr{hash}{3f71afbcde39f096d711d45fa2c17bc7}%% <----- put the correct hash here
      {\global\toggletrue{ellipsis}%
       \ifgiveninits
        {\usebibmacro{name:given-family}
           {\namepartfamily}
           {\namepartgiveni}
           {\namepartprefix}
           {\namepartsuffix}}
        {\usebibmacro{name:given-family}
           {\namepartfamily}
           {\namepartgiven}
           {\namepartprefix}
           {\namepartsuffix}}}%
      {\stepcounter{namesnotimportant}%
       \iftoggle{ellipsis}
         {\addcomma\space\textellipsis\global\togglefalse{ellipsis}\isdot}
         {}}}%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test {\ifnumequal{\value{listcount}}{\value{liststop}}}
    and
    (test \ifmorenames
     or test {\ifnumcomp{\value{namesnotimportant}}{>}{0}})
  }
    {\andothersdelim\bibstring{andothers}}
    {}}

\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{given-family-etal}
\DeclareNameAlias{author}{given-family-etal}
\DeclareNameAlias{editor}{given-family-etal}
\DeclareNameAlias{translator}{given-family-etal}

\begin{document}
\nocite{cheshkov,breitling,aksin,worman,nussbaum,geer,sigfridsson}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

you thus get

[image: reference section of MWE]

---

If you only want this special format for `\fullcite`, move the four `\DeclareNameAlias` lines into the pre-code hook of `\usedriver` in `\DeclareCiteCommand{\fullcite}` like so

```
\DeclareCiteCommand{\fullcite}
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usedriver
     {\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{given-family-etal}%
      \DeclareNameAlias{author}{given-family-etal}%
      \DeclareNameAlias{editor}{given-family-etal}%
      \DeclareNameAlias{translator}{given-family-etal}}
     {\thefield{entrytype}}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}
```

If you want to define a special command for that so that you can use 'normal' `\fullcite` and the new name format simultaneously, you could define a starred `\fullcite*` via

```
\DeclareCiteCommand*{\fullcite}
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usedriver
     {\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{given-family-etal}%
      \DeclareNameAlias{author}{given-family-etal}%
      \DeclareNameAlias{editor}{given-family-etal}%
      \DeclareNameAlias{translator}{given-family-etal}}
     {\thefield{entrytype}}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}
```

instead.

---

If you want to 'filter' several names (additionally also, say `{Tajima}, T.`), you can combine the hash comparisons into one `\ifboolexpr`. Just use

```
\ifboolexpr{test {\iffieldequalstr{hash}{f9c1127a739dfe7ad337f89c98aebf51}}
            or 
            test {\iffieldequalstr{hash}{67bbebbc19c3d65d07202eac52047d5e}}}%% <----- put the correct hash here
```

instead of `\iffieldequalstr{hash}{f9c1127a739dfe7ad337f89c98aebf51}` in `\DeclareNameFormat{given-family-etal}`:

```
\DeclareNameFormat{given-family-etal}{%
  \letbibmacro{name:delim}{name:etal:delim}%
  \ifnumcomp{\value{listcount}}{=}{1}
    {\setcounter{namesnotimportant}{0}%
     \global\toggletrue{ellipsis}}
    {}%
  \ifboolexpr{test {\ifnumcomp{\value{listcount}}{=}{1}}
              or test {\ifnumcomp{\value{listtotal}}{=}{2}}}
    {\ifgiveninits
      {\usebibmacro{name:given-family}
         {\namepartfamily}
         {\namepartgiveni}
         {\namepartprefix}
         {\namepartsuffix}}
      {\usebibmacro{name:given-family}
         {\namepartfamily}
         {\namepartgiven}
         {\namepartprefix}
         {\namepartsuffix}}}%
    {\ifboolexpr{test {\iffieldequalstr{hash}{f9c1127a739dfe7ad337f89c98aebf51}}
                 or 
                 test {\iffieldequalstr{hash}{67bbebbc19c3d65d07202eac52047d5e}}}%% <----- put the correct hash here
      {\global\toggletrue{ellipsis}%
       \ifgiveninits
        {\usebibmacro{name:given-family}
           {\namepartfamily}
           {\namepartgiveni}
           {\namepartprefix}
           {\namepartsuffix}}
        {\usebibmacro{name:given-family}
           {\namepartfamily}
           {\namepartgiven}
           {\namepartprefix}
           {\namepartsuffix}}}%
      {\stepcounter{namesnotimportant}%
       \iftoggle{ellipsis}
         {\addcomma\space\textellipsis\global\togglefalse{ellipsis}\isdot}
         {}}}%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test {\ifnumequal{\value{listcount}}{\value{liststop}}}
    and
    (test \ifmorenames
     or test {\ifnumcomp{\value{namesnotimportant}}{>}{0}})
  }
    {\andothersdelim\bibstring{andothers}}
    {}}
```

Comment: I am also wondering if it is possible to switch back and forth between this new formatting and the default?

Comment: @FrankBreitling If your version is from around October 2014 it is way older than version 3.3, in that case you can try to get the code in the other answer running. But it might be that that doesn't even work because your `biblatex` is really old (certainly more than two years now).

Comment: @FrankBreitling I'm not sure what you mean by 'switch back and forth'. The new name format is really only enabled by the four `\DeclareNameAlias` lines. If you comment these out, you get the standard format, if you uncomment them you get the new format.

Comment: Sorry, this was my mistake. It wasn't testing, but still stable. That's why the package was so old. Now it works! I will remove my first comment. How can I check my biblatex version?

Comment: I mean if it is possible to use for example \fullcite{} at one part of the document and obtain this new reference format and later obtain the bibliography with the default format.

Comment: That's great! And can I also always show two names like Breitling and Tajima for example?

Comment: I have modified your example to a macro which I can then load with \input{} if you agree.

Comment: Can you also tell me how to make it work with \DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first} which I was using?

Comment: @FrankBreitling, The edit you proposed made the MWE not compilable, that is: copy/pasting it won't work. Saving big chunks of code in separate files is a great practice to get organized, but here it's kinda problematic. If you still wish to edit the question, use another `\begin{filecontents}{file.ext}...\end{filecontents}` to make the `.tex` file (then the code will be compilable. `:)`

Comment: @GuilhermeZanotelli Ok, then how can I revert it?

Comment: @FrankBreitling, no Need to, it's being revised, most likely it won't be approved (I rejected it at least) you can suggest another edit on top of it, I think. If not, Access the edits tab from this question and try to delete the edit or "rollback".

Comment: How can I redefine my fullcite command if I have \usepackage[backend=biber,natbib,style=authoryear,dashed=fal‌​se,maxbibnames=3,min‌​bibnames=3,maxcitena‌​mes=3,uniquelist=fal‌​se,maxalphanames=1,l‌​abelalpha,sorting=an‌​yt,doi=true,isbn=fal‌​se,url=false,eprint=‌​true]{biblatex} in my preamble which I need for the bibliography.

Comment: @moewe I can't reproduce this solution under TeX Live 2019 or 2020. The ellipses are dropped before the hashed author.

F. Breitling **et al.** (Feb. 2001). ‘Laser pointing stabilization and control in the
submicroradian regime with neural networks’. In: Review of Scientific In-
struments 72, pp. 1339–1342.
S. Cheshkov **and** F. Breitling et al. (May 2001). ‘Emittance control in Laser
Wakefield Accelerator’. In: American Institute of Physics Conference Series.
Vol. 569, pp. 163–176.

Comment: @CatThatKilledCuriosity A while ago `biblatex` introduced some grouping in the name formats. You'll need a few `\global`s now. See the edit, please.

Comment: The proposed answer, although great, does not seem to work properly with `biblatex` loading options `sorting=none` and `maxnames=999`: using these returns the reference list with "et al." for each entry after the first occurrence of the ellipsis print, even those with a single author.

Comment: @dr_wann Thanks for pointing this out. Does the edited solution work better for you?

Comment: This is great! Is there a way to alternate between using the style and not using it if I use `\nocite{*}` e.g. through a keyword or anything in the `.bib` file?

Comment: Also, it would be cool if there was an option to still specify the amount of authors to display normally before switching to "et al." since now this is set to `maxnames=999` to parse all of them I think.