# sorting authorname and highlight it in bold

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, sorting, cv

I used to use the piece of code below (that I actually found here) to highlight in my name bold  in my bibliography for CV or thesis. It worked just fine but for the last 3 weeks or so I get a bunch of errors whereas neither the code nor my .bib file were modified. I understood that some options have been simplified which impact the code. any chance to get an updated code for this function.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,numbered,fontsize=11pt]{scrartcl} % KOMA-article class
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[protrusion=true,expansion=true]{microtype}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amsthm}     % Math packages
\usepackage{graphicx}                    % Enable pdflatex
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}            % Colors by their 'svgnames'
\usepackage{geometry}
%\textheight=700px                    % Saving trees ;-)
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blue,urlcolor=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{etaremune}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{attachfile}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
%sorting section
\usepackage[backend=biber,sorting=ddatent,style=phys,isbn=true]{biblatex}

%sorting by date 
\DeclareSortingScheme{ddatent}{
    \sort{
        \field{presort}
    }
    \sort[final]{
        \field{sortkey}
    }
    \sort[direction=descending]{
        \field[strside=left,strwidth=4]{sortyear}
        \field[strside=left,strwidth=4]{year}
        \literal{9999}
    }
    \sort[direction=descending]{
        \field[padside=left,padwidth=2,padchar=0]{month}
        \literal{00}
    }
    \sort[direction=descending]{
        \field[padside=left,padwidth=2,padchar=0]{day}
        \literal{00}
    }
    \sort[direction=descending]{
        \field[padside=left,padwidth=4,padchar=0]{volume}
        \literal{9999}
    }
    \sort{
        \name{sortname}
        \name{author}
        \name{editor}
        \name{translator}
        \field{sorttitle}
        \field{title}
    }
    \sort{
        \field{sorttitle}
        \field{title}
    }
}

\addbibresource{mybiblio2016.bib}


\setlength{\biblabelsep}{0pt}

%Make Bold author name
\newcommand{\makeauthorbold}[1]{%
    \DeclareNameFormat{author}{%
        \ifnumequal{\value{listcount}}{1}
        {\ifnumequal{\value{liststop}}{1}
            {\expandafter\ifstrequal{##1}{#1}{\textbf{##1\addcomma\addspace ##4\addcomma\isdot}}{##1\addcomma\addspace ##4\addcomma\isdot}}
            {\expandafter\ifstrequal{##1}{#1}{\textbf{##1\addcomma\addspace ##4}}{##1\addcomma\addspace ##4}}}
        {\ifnumless{\value{listcount}}{\value{liststop}}
            {\expandafter\ifstrequal{##1}{#1}{\textbf{\addcomma\addspace ##1\addcomma\addspace ##4}}{\addcomma\addspace ##1\addcomma\addspace ##4}}
            {\expandafter\ifstrequal{##1}{#1}{\textbf{\addcomma\addspace ##1\addcomma\addspace ##4\addcomma\isdot}}{\addcomma\addspace ##1\addcomma\addspace ##4\addcomma\isdot}}%
        }%
    }%
}
\makeauthorbold{Myname}


\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumberwidth}{}


%%% Papers
\newpage
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[type=article,title={\uppercase{Journal articles}}]
\printbibliography[type=inproceedings,title={\uppercase{Conference papers}}]
\printbibliography[type=book,title={\uppercase{Books chapters}}]
\printbibliography[type=patent,title={\uppercase{Patents}}]
\printbibliography[type=unpublished,title={\uppercase{Presentations}}]
\printbibliography[type=inreference,title={\uppercase{Invited talks}}]
\printbibliography[type=incollection,title={\uppercase{Posters}}]
\printbibliography[type=report,title={\uppercase{Technical notes}}]
\printbibliography[type=thesis,title={\uppercase{Thesis}}]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can [Highlight an author in bibliography using biblatex allowing bibliography style to format it](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/274436/35864) and its linked questions help you? If not, it would be very helpful if you could provide [a full MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864) that shows how you use the code from above (you may also want to add a link to where you found the code if it was on this site).

Comment: Dear Moewe, I tried a few code in the former answers but i still get an incredible number of errors related to the last piece of code and Makeauthorbold function, I am stuck. I pasted part of the full code in the question hope it helps.

Comment: I recommend using the functionality shown here going forward - it was designed for this sort of situation and doesn't require any messing about with internals . http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73136/make-specific-author-bold-using-biblatex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you use the solution from [Highlight an author in bibliography using biblatex allowing bibliography style to format it](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/274436/35864) which in turn is based on [Audrey](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/4483/audrey)'s solution to [Make specific author bold using biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/73136/35864),  but with hashes instead of string comparison.

Since in `biblatex` 3.3 some internal macros were renamed (see [Biblatex 3.3 name formatting](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/299036/35864)) you now need to redefine `name:family`, `name:given-family` and `name:family-given`.

You can add hashes of names that should be highlighted as follows. Those hashes can be found by looking at the `.bbl` file. More details [in the other answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/274571/35864).

```
\forcsvlist{\listadd\boldnames}
  {{5e1df516fe8816ee66169b8616522816}}
```

MWE (with slightly fewer packages)

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[protrusion=true,expansion=true]{microtype}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber,sorting=ddatent,style=phys,isbn=true]{biblatex}

\usepackage{xpatch}

\newcommand*{\boldnames}{}

\newcommand*{\doboldnames}[1]{%
  \iffieldequalstr{hash}{#1}
    {\bfseries\listbreak}
    {}}%

\newbibmacro*{name:bold}{%
  \forlistloop{\doboldnames}{\boldnames}}

\xpretobibmacro{name:family}{\begingroup\usebibmacro{name:bold}}{}{}
\xpretobibmacro{name:given-family}{\begingroup\usebibmacro{name:bold}}{}{}
\xpretobibmacro{name:family-given}{\begingroup\usebibmacro{name:bold}}{}{}
\xpretobibmacro{name:delim}{\begingroup\normalfont}{}{}

\xapptobibmacro{name:family}{\endgroup}{}{}
\xapptobibmacro{name:given-family}{\endgroup}{}{}
\xapptobibmacro{name:family-given}{\endgroup}{}{}
\xapptobibmacro{name:delim}{\endgroup}{}{}

\renewcommand*{\boldnames}{}
\forcsvlist{\listadd\boldnames}
  {{5e1df516fe8816ee66169b8616522816}}

%sorting by date 
\DeclareSortingScheme{ddatent}{
  \sort{
    \field{presort}
  }
  \sort[final]{
    \field{sortkey}
  }
  \sort[direction=descending]{
    \field[strside=left,strwidth=4]{sortyear}
    \field[strside=left,strwidth=4]{year}
    \literal{9999}
  }
  \sort[direction=descending]{
    \field[padside=left,padwidth=2,padchar=0]{month}
    \literal{00}
  }
  \sort[direction=descending]{
    \field[padside=left,padwidth=2,padchar=0]{day}
        \literal{00}
  }
  \sort[direction=descending]{
    \field[padside=left,padwidth=4,padchar=0]{volume}
    \literal{9999}
  }
  \sort{
    \name{sortname}
    \name{author}
    \name{editor}
    \name{translator}
    \field{sorttitle}
    \field{title}
  }
  \sort{
    \field{sorttitle}
    \field{title}
  }
}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@incollection{Silva:2014a,
  title={Radio Resource Management for Device-to-Device Communications in Long Term Evolution Networks},
  author={Carlos F. M. Silva and Silva, Jr., Jos\'{e} Mairton B. and Tarcisio F. Maciel},
  booktitle={Resource Allocation and {MIMO} for {4G} and Beyond},
  publisher={Springer Science+Business Media},
  year=2014,
  address={New York, USA},
  editor={Francisco Rodrigo Porto Cavalcanti},
  pages={105-156},
  doi={10.1007/978-1-4614-8057-0_3},
  isbn={978-1-4614-8056-3},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\setlength{\biblabelsep}{0pt}

\begin{document}
\fullcite{Silva:2014a}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks Moewe, your MWE works fine just need to take the various hashes related to my name in the .bbl. just one more point that bothers me, I d like to get rid of the numbering since it is for a CV bibliography, I can't even by using : \DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumberwidth}{}
\setlength{\biblabelsep}{0pt}  , any suugestions?

Comment: got it just need to put \DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumberwidth}{} \setlength{\biblabelsep}{0pt}   just after the \nocite(*) function. Thanks