# Natbib authors bold

Tags: bibliographies, natbib, bold, apa-style

I usually use natbib

```
\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}
...
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\bibliography{references}
```

to read in the references. I've seen in a paper this style with bold author names and was wondering how I can modify the bibstyle to have that as well?
[This does it biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/381707/bolding-author-name), but I think it wouldn't work for natbib?

[image]

Comment: Are you sure this style was used? I hardly ever recall any styles that uses bold authors

Comment: It's a working paper, I'd like to use it for my working paper template. I think at that stage we're free and I find it aesthetically pleasing.

Comment: `natbib` is primarily a citation management package. As such, it does *not* govern how the individual entries in a bibliography are formatted. Instead of asking how you may achieve your formatting objective with `natbib` -- to which there really is but one answer, *viz.*, "it can't be done" -- it would be more promising if you mentioned a particular bib style you wish to work with and asked how it would have to be modified in order to achieve your formatting objective.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry that I can only come up with an approximate solution. Hopefully, more capable people of TeX.SE will provide better solutions.
My `c.tex` is as follows.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[authorformat={and,firstnotreversed,abbrv},bibformat={compress},dota\
fter={bibentry}]{jurabib}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{jurabib}
\bibliography{c}
\end{document}
```

My `c.bib` is as follows.

```
@incollection{Ahmed94,
  author =   {Ahmed, Bashir and J. Gregory Robinson},
  year =     1994,
  title =    {Estimates of Emigration of the Foreign-Born
                  Population: 1980--1990},
  booktitle =    {Census Bureau Population Division No. 9},
}

@article{Akay17,
  author =   {Akay, Alpaslan and Olivier Bargain and Klaus
                  F. Zimmermann},
  year =     2017,
  title =    {Home Sweet Home? Macroeconomic Conditions in Home
                  Countries and the Well-Being of Migrants},
  journal =  {Journal of Human Resources},
  volume =   52,
  number =   2,
  pages =    {351-373},
}
```

[image]