# Apply a string replacement on the citation as returned by \cite

Tags: biblatex, citing, substitution

I have `biblatex` with options

```
\usepackage[backend=bibtex, style=authoryear]{biblatex}
```

The citations made with `\cite` look like this: `Smith, 2019` or `Smith and Baker, 2019` and so on. I would like to define a command that automatically replaces the occurrence of my name with my initials. Namely I need

```
\cite{SmithsPaper}  % --> Smith, 2019
\cite{MyPaper}      % --> Manny, 2019
%%%
\newcite{SmithsPaper}  % --> Smith, 2019
\newcite{MyPaper}      % --> MC, 2019
```

I have tried with the package `xstring` to do something like

```
\newcommand{\newcite}[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \edef\@temp{\cite{#1}}%
  \StrSubstitute{\@temp}{Manny}{MC}
  \endgroup
}
```

The problem is that I can't figure out how to tell LaTeX to expand `\cite{#1}`. As a result the citation comes out without the replacement. If I change `\cite{#1}` by simply `#1` and I call `\newcite{bla Manny bla}` it gives `bla MC bla` as expected.

It shouldn't be relevant but I'm using this within the beamer documentclass.

Comment: `\cite` isn't completely expandable and defined `\protected`, so the short answer is, you can't do this by expanding `\cite`. But there are some real `biblatex` experts here, so maybe one of those has an idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [Skillmon](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/117050/skillmon) says in the comments: `\cite...` commands are not expandable, so you can't (easily) perform `xstring` replacements on them. Instead I would try and let `biblatex` do the replacement directly.

One way to do that is by using the approach of [my answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/416416/35864) to [Make specific author bold using biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/73136/35864) (see also [Highlight an author in bibliography using biblatex allowing bibliography style to format it](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/274436/35864)). The idea is to obtain the unique name hash computed by Biber for the name you want to replace and then replace it with the initials in `\mkbibcompletename`.

Note that this particular implementation requires at least `biblatex` version 3.13 (2019-08-17).

You can request replacement of a name with `\replacenamewith{<name>}{<replacement>}`

```
\replacenamewith{Emma Sigfridsson}{ES}
```

The replacement can be styled by redefining `\mkbinamereplacement`.

Some more explanations can be found in the links above.

*Warning*, this document will overwrite the file `<name of the main TeX file/\jobname>-replacenames.bib` without warning. The name of this overwritten helper file can be changed by redefining `\hlblx@bibfile@name`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\makeatletter
\def\hlblx@bibfile@name{\jobname -replacenames.bib}
\newwrite\hlblx@bibfile
\immediate\openout\hlblx@bibfile=\hlblx@bibfile@name

\newcounter{hlblx@name}
\setcounter{hlblx@name}{0}

\newcommand*{\hlblx@writenametobib}[2]{%
  \stepcounter{hlblx@name}%
  \edef\hlblx@tmp@nocite{%
    \noexpand\AfterPreamble{%
      \noexpand\setbox0\noexpand\vbox{%
        \noexpand\hlblx@getmethehash{hlblx@name@\the\value{hlblx@name}}}}%
  }%
  \hlblx@tmp@nocite
  \immediate\write\hlblx@bibfile{%
    @misc{hlblx@name@\the\value{hlblx@name},
          author = {\unexpanded{#1}}, %
          note   = {\unexpanded{#2}}, %
          options = {dataonly=true},}%
  }%
}

\AtEndDocument{%
  \closeout\hlblx@bibfile}

\addbibresource{\hlblx@bibfile@name}

\newcommand*{\hlblx@hashextract@i}[1]{%
  \csgdef{replacename@\thefield{fullhash}}{#1}}

\DeclareNameFormat{hlblx@hashextract}{%
  \usefield{\hlblx@hashextract@i}{note}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\hlblx@getmethehash}
  {}
  {\printnames[hlblx@hashextract][1-999]{author}}
  {}
  {}

\renewcommand*{\mkbibcompletename}[1]{%
  \ifcsundef{replacename@\thefield{hash}}
    {#1}
    {\mkbinamereplacement{\csuse{replacename@\thefield{hash}}}}}

% {<name>}{<replacement>}
\newcommand*{\replacenamewith}{\hlblx@writenametobib}
\makeatother

% formatting for the replacement
\newcommand*{\mkbinamereplacement}[1]{\textbf{#1}}

% declare a replacement for a name
% this command can be used several times
\replacenamewith{Emma Sigfridsson}{ES}

\begin{document}
\cite{sigfridsson}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: ES and Ryde 1998]