# Modify print of Author in text and bibliography of BibLaTeX

Tags: biblatex

I have a question concerning printing of citekeys (from citestyle) and an authors name in the text and bibliography. Consider the following MWE

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[style=authoryear-comp,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{key1,
    author = {Art, Bee and Cee, De},
    title = {F},
    journal = {G},
    year = {2020}
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
    \cite{key1}
    
    \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

And say I am “Bee Art” and on my slides I would like to not show my name in full but an abbreviation. That is

1. The current text key prints as “Art and Cee 2020” which I would like to postprocess to “AB and Cee 2020”
2. The Bibliography “Art, Bee and De Cee (2020). “F”. In: G.” should read as “AB and De Cee (2020). “F”. In: G.”

I would like to be able to identify the author by Firstname (Given name) and Lastname, so let's assume the author “Bee Art” is unique.

Can something like the steps 1 and 2 be done in post processing, i.e. without modifying the `.bib` file?

For best of cases I would like to have two commands to set this i.e. setting

```
\renewcommand{\shortenFirstName}{Bee}
\renewcommand{\shortenLastName}{Art}
```

does the two points above (or in other words setting these two to `De` and `Cee` respectively shortens the second author as described above).

How can I hook into BibLaTeX like this?

Until now I Modified the `.bbl` manually, but this has to be redone after every `biber`, run, so I would like to see, whether it'S possible to do this directly.

Comment: Have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/519654/35864.

Comment: That works like a charm. I noticed that I did not use the name consistently in my bib (once with first name was abbreviated in the bib), after that it works really neat. So this is a duplicate of said link. I just did not think to search for that title :)

Comment: Well, I guess the other question turned out to be an XY-problem, so finding it is tricky. You can use `\replacenamewith` several times, so different name versions in the `.bib` are no problem and need not be changed. Since you say this question is a duplicate I will close it as such. (Even though the titles are different, there is little point in copying the answer from there over here, so I think closing is sensible.)

Comment: I think this question might be found by some, they then get over to your solution, and that really solves this. Ah – I did not yet check for multiple replacements, will do that, too. But it's also nice to have one author unified in a bib-file. Thanks again for the help (since I can't accept an answer now!)