# How to treat the output of a command as an "ordinary text"?

Tags: macros, expansion

In the following example, how can I treat the output of `\cite` as it was a simple string of text?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=numeric-comp]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{A,
    title = {A Bla},
    author = {A Foo}
}

@book{B,
    title = {B Bla},
    author = {B Foo}
}

@book{C,
    title = {C Bla},
    author = {C Foo}
}

@book{D,
    title = {D Bla},
    author = {D Foo}
}

@book{E,
    title = {E Bla},
    author = {E Foo}
}

@book{F,
    title = {F Bla},
    author = {F Foo}
}

@book{G,
    title = {G Bla},
    author = {G Foo}
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\usepackage{listofitems}
\usepackage{scontents}

\begin{document}
  \nocite{*}

  I would like this example:
  
  \setsepchar{,}
  \readlist\foo{\cite{A,B,C,E,F,G}}
  Show items: \showitems\foo\par
  Term 1: \foo[1]\par

  would give the same output as this example: 

  \setsepchar{,}
  \readlist\bar{[1-3,5-7]}
  Show items: \showitems\bar\par
  Term 1: \bar[1]\par
  Term 2: \bar[2]\par
     
  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You have (at least) two issues: `\cite` is not expandable, and you have invoked `\readlist` in a manner that will not do any expansion on `\cite` even if that were possible.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking, because with just `\cite{A,B,C,E,F,G}` I get `[1–3,5–7]`

Comment: @egreg I would like to treat [1-3, 5-7] as a string, not as a unique block.

Comment: What's a string?  Seriously, context is missing.

Comment: @egreg An alphanumeric set of chars, like a piece of ordinary text. I think in LaTeX "string" has another meaning...

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/519654/apply-a-string-replacement-on-the-citation-as-returned-by-cite

Comment: @Marijn That's similar to what I need, but I need to identify the groups 1-3 and 5-7.

Comment: @CarLaTeX I mentioned that question because the problem and proposed approach is related (i.e., string processing on `\cite` results) and the reason why this can't be done is mentioned in comments and in the answer (`\cite` is not expandable). Other than that the answer does not apply to your current problem, so it was more intended as general background information that may give you some insight in the problem and possible approaches, not as a solution to the question you asked here.

Comment: @Marijn Yes, I know, I replied only for others that can read and think it's a duplicate