# How do I replace a specific string with its bold version?

Tags: strings, xstring, bibentry

I want to bold my own name in the publication section of my CV.

I have tried:

```
\usepackage{xstring}

\newcommand{\highlightname}[1]{
  \StrSubstitute{#1}{My Name}{\textbf{My Name}}
}

\begin{enumerate}
  \item \highlightname{\bibentry{x-cvpr24}}
  \item \highlightname{\bibentry{y-cvpr24}}
\end{enumerate}
```

But this does not work.

Comment: Here's a way to avoid "needs details or clarity" next time: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that/10137#10137

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To bold your own name in the bibliography entries within your LaTeX document, you will need to modify the `bibentry` entries in your `.bib` file. Specifically, you will wrap your name with `\textbf{}` command. Here is how you can do it:

1. Open your `.bib` file (where your references are stored).
2. Locate the entries you want to change.
3. In these entries, find your name and replace it with `\textbf{Your Name}`.

After you've made these changes, save the `.bib` file and recompile your LaTeX document. Your name should now appear in bold in the bibliography section.

Comment: There are much better ways of doing this. Look for any answer by moewe e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/274436/highlight-an-author-in-bibliography-using-biblatex-allowing-bibliography-style-t, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73136/make-specific-author-bold-using-biblatex/416416#416416 and links. Your solution will break sorting, formatting and labelling, as well (of course) as affecting any other documents which use these entries. If you don't want to use Biblatex, conditional use of `@string` to define a shorthand would be safer.

Comment: Please provide compilable code in questions and answers. This is much more useful than snippets.