# Biblatex: Citation in footnotes. When the same reference appears twice, it should use the first footnote number

Tags: biblatex

I am using biblatex and I don't know how to achieve the following structure of referencing.

If an article is referenced for the first time, it should give the full citation in footnotes.
Every time an article gets referenced, it should give the footnote number of the first full citation.

### I tried the following...

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=footnote]{biblatex}
\begin{document}

Here's the first citataion \cite{ref1}. And here is the same on the same page \cite{ref1}.
\clearpage
And here is the same one on another page \cite{ref1}.

\end{document}
```

---

### ...but it creates the following.

---

**First page:**

Here's the first citation^1. And here is the same on the same page^2.

**First page footnotes:**

1) *full citation of ref1*

2) Ibid.

**Second page:**
And here is the same one on another page^3

**Second page footnotes:**

3)*Short citation of ref1* (see n.1)

---

### How I want it to be is:

---

**First page:**

Here's the first citation^1. And here is the same on the same page^1.

**First page footnotes:**

1) *full citation ref 1*

**Second page:**
And here is the same one on another page^1

**Second page footnotes:**
*No footnotes as no new article was referenced.*

Comment: That has the disadvantage that in a long article people will have to skip back all the time to identify citations. Since footnote numbers are not correlated with page numbers that can be a very tedious task. Do you really want to place such a burden on your reader?

Comment: Yes, I do. I am aware that it is not convenient and less readable, but my situation requires it. Thank a lot for your interest and possible help.

Comment: But there seem to be enough people interested in something like that, please see [biblatex repeated citations in footnotes that point back to earlier footnotes](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/200286/35864), [Repeat the same reference in footnote on different pages](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/71526/35864), [Multiply cited reference in footnotes](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/82670/35864).

Comment: There are also [biblatex : which style for a footnote once then nothing?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/20637/35864), [biblatex: is there a command analogous to \ifciteseen but within one page?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/35673/35864).

Comment: Did any of the linked questions help you? If not, what did you try and how did it not work for you?

Comment: I successfully used http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20637/biblatex-which-style-for-a-footnote-once-then-nothing replacing chem-acs with numeric-comp. Thanks for all your comments.