# foot cite in Beamer using IEEE standard

Tags: beamer, biblatex, citing

I am using `beamer` and I need to have IEEE Trans. style for citing the papers in `\footfullcite`. The result my compile is this:

As you see, this is not in IEEE standard format (no need for ISSN and etc.). Moreover, I would like to have the author's name for citing instead of "numerical/alphabetical order". Would you help me to do that? Thanks.

[image]

---

```
\documentclass[10pt,xcolor={dvipsnames}]{beamer}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\setbeamersize{text margin left=8mm,text margin right=8mm} 
\usepackage{textpos}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{array}

\graphicspath{{Figs/}}
\usepackage[outdir=./]{epstopdf}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\usepackage[style=authortitle,backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{refs.bib}


\mode<presentation> {

\usecolortheme{whale}
\setbeamercolor{section in head/foot}{bg=black!80!blue,fg=white}

\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
}

\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{booktabs} 
\setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{sidecap}


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

%@article{gardner2006cyclostationarity,
%   title = "Cyclostationarity: Half a century of research",
%   journal = "Signal Processing",
%   volume = "86",
%   number = "4",
%   pages = "639 - 697",
%   year = "2006",
%   author = "William A. Gardner and Antonio Napolitano and Luigi Paura",
%   keywords = "Cyclostationarity, Almost-cyclostationary time series, Almost-cyclostationary processes, Bibliography"
%}

\frametitle{\textbf{What is Cyclostationarity?} - 1}

\vspace*{-0.5cm}
\setbeamertemplate{itemize items}[square]
\begin{itemize}
    \item There is a special type of non-stationary stochastic processes when their statistical properties vary periodically with time called {\color{Blue}cyclostationary} processes~{\color{red} [Gardner'06]}. 
\end{itemize}

\vspace*{5cm}
\rule{0.45\linewidth}{0.2pt}\\
\tiny {\color{red} [Gardner'06]} {W. A. Gardner et al., ``Cyclostationarity: Half a century of research," Signal Processing, vol. 86, no. 4, pp. 639 – 697, 2006.}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please make a [minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407) and also explicitly add what this citation should look like.

Comment: @samcarter: I provided a sample of what I want to do automatically. Would you please help me how to do it?

Comment: Can you make a [minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407)?

Comment: The reference you provided is not related to Beamer.

Comment: No it is not. But constructing a MWEB works the same for beamer as for every other class.

Comment: @samcarter: I tried to minimize the code to give the picture like above.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 2):

You can use `biblatex-ieee`'s `style=ieee-alphabetic` together with my answer to [Numbering of citation in beamer with split frame](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/445985/35864)

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[style=ieee-alphabetic, backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\mkblankfootnote}[1]{%
  \begingroup
    \renewcommand\thefootnote{}%
    \footnotetext{\bibfootnotewrapper{#1}}%
  \endgroup
}

\newcommand*{\mkbibsupercite}[1]{%
  \def\cbx@savedcites{\cbx@footfullcite}%
  \mkbibbrackets{#1}%
  \ifx\cbx@savedkeys\@empty
  \else
    \cbx@savedcites
  \fi}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\supercite}[\mkbibsupercite]
  {\gdef\cbx@savedkeys{}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cite}%
     {}%
   \xappto\cbx@savedkeys{\thefield{entrykey},}}
  {\supercitedelim}
  {\protected@xappto\cbx@savedcites{%
     [\thefield{prenote}][\thefield{postnote}]{\cbx@savedkeys}}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\cbx@footfullcite}
  {}
  {\mkblankfootnote{%
     \printtext[labelalphawidth]{%
       \usebibmacro{cite}%
     }%
   \setunit{\addspace}%
   \usedriver
     {\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{default}}
     {\thefield{entrytype}}}}
  {}
  {}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{\textbf{What is Cyclostationarity?} - 1}

\begin{itemize}
    \item There is a special type of non-stationary stochastic processes when their statistical properties vary periodically with time called cyclostationary processes \supercite{sigfridsson}. 
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: The citation label is [SR98] the footnote (without number) reads: [SR98] E. Sigfridsson and U. Ryde, “Comparison of methods for deriving atomic charges from the electrostatic potential and moments,” Journal of Computational Chemistry, vol. 19, no. 4, pp. 377–395, 1998. doi:10.1002/(SICI)1096-987X(199803)19:4<377::AID-JCC1>3.0.CO;2-P.]

Comment: Thanks @moewe for your answer. But what I asked here is quite different from your answer.

Comment: @Amin I guess the main thing is there: You asked for IEEE and this is IEEE style. The citation also uses the author name. What exactly do you want to change? Do you insist on alphabetic citations (SR98)?

Comment: Yes. In the example above, I showed that. That is in alphabetic citations but with IEEE style.

Comment: @Amin Have a look at the edited version, please.

Comment: I tried that but I got the error: "Undefined control sequence. \end{frame}"

Comment: Thanks @moewe. When I use it separately as a test file, it works. But, when I want to use it in the main file of my latex file, it gives the above error.

Comment: @Amin Try again. I found and hopefully fixed a weird error. But if it works in a test document and not in your real one you will have to investigate why and try to find an MWE that reproduces the error.

Comment: Now, it works. But there are two points: 1. When I want to use \supercite inside a block, it shows the citation inside the block whereas it should be at the end of page; 2. As it is shown in the above example, I like to have \textit{Apostrophe} between the first author's name (Not all the authors) and the year of publication. Moreover, this part [first author's name' year] Would you please edit your answer with these attributes?

Comment: Moreover, there is also one point: I noticed that when I have citation to one reference two times in one page, then your code shows the reference twice at the end of page whereas that should be one. I need to avoid such repetition.

Comment: @Amin Sorry, footnotes are complicated in LaTeX and even more so in `beamer`. I know if no elegant, automatic way to break out of a box. With BibTeX there is also no way to customise the label to yield "Sigfridsson'98", though that should be possible with Biber. The repetitions are also hard to get rid of, though it can be done: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/35673/35864