# \footcite does not show up in beamer

Tags: beamer, biblatex, bibtex, citing

I am trying to use `\footcite` in one of the slides however the reference is not showing up. The reference that I cite is:

```
@article{question,
  title={My article},
  author={Joe, Smith},
  year={2020}
}
```

Minimal working example is provided below.

```
\documentclass[hyperref={pdfpagelabels=false}]{beamer} 
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\bibliography{References}


 \begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Deneme}
    Here \footcite{question}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\printbibliography
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Does ```\footfullcite``` work any better?

Comment: It did work, but I don't understand. In another beamer file, I was able to use \footcite. Maybe there are some extra settings. In any case, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example the citation *is* showing up - but arguably in a very unhelpful format.

With most standard styles, the command `\footcite` just typesets the normal citation label you'd get if you were to say `\cite` in a footnote.

The example loads `biblatex` as `\usepackage{biblatex}`, so requests `style=numeric`, which means you are using a numeric style where `\cite` (usually) produces a simple number.

That explains what you are seeing here. `\footcite` produces a footnote containing the citation label of the entry. The output is even more confusing since your version of `beamer` patches `biblatex`'s bibliography output to replace the label numbers in the bibliography with cute little icons, so you have no way of knowing what each number refers to. (This is not the case in my version of `biblatex` and `beamer`, but I'm not sure if that is intentional or just a temporary thing.)

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\bibliography{biblatex-examples}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Deneme}
  \begin{itemize}
    \item lorem \footcite{sigfridsson}
    \item ipsum \footcite{worman}
    \item dolor \footcite{sigfridsson}
    \item sit \footcite{nussbaum}
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\printbibliography
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: Footnote 1 shows "2.", fn. 2 says "3.", fn. 3 has "2." and fn. 4 shows "1."]

You might get a result that is closer to what you hoped for, if you use `biblatex` with the `verbose` style. Note that in that case there are no citation numbers at all, the only numbers you are seeing are the continuous footnote numbers.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\usepackage[style=verbose]{biblatex}
\bibliography{biblatex-examples}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Deneme}
  \begin{itemize}
    \item lorem \footcite{sigfridsson}
    \item ipsum \footcite{worman}
    \item dolor \footcite{sigfridsson}
    \item sit \footcite{nussbaum}
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\printbibliography
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Often what people are hoping for are numeric citations with a sorted 'mini bibliography' of references cited on that slide at the bottom. That is *much*, *much* harder to achieve and I'm not aware of a good and robust solution for that at the moment. [footcite - repeated references](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/543557/35864) looked promising, but depending on the exact requirements you have in mind, a lot more may need to be done.