# Remove "ibid" in footer citation with autocite

Tags: biblatex

This is the header of my document

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{import}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\textwidth=450pt\oddsidemargin=10pt

\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\setlength{\parindent}{1em} %indentazione paragrafo
\setlength{\parskip}{0.5em} % spazio tra due paragrafi
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5} %interlinea

\usepackage{float}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=verbose-ibid, ibidpage=false]{biblatex}
\bibliography{bibliography}
```

I'm using `\autocite{}` and biblatex package to cite into the footer page my references. But I'm in truble when I cite twice an article because into the footer appears the string "ibid".

[image]

How can I insert a cross-refence and avoid to have the "ibid" on the footer page ? Thanks

Comment: What do you want to happen instead? `verbose-ibid` is a style that produces a full citation in the footnotes on a first cite, a shorter author-title reference on subsequent citations and "ibid." when you cite the same source several times in direct succession. Are you looking for `style=verbose-ibid,`?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I would like to cite the same source twice in succession, but without making appear `ibid` in the footer.

Comment: Does that mean you want to reuse the same footnote number in that case? Or do you want a normal short citation as in `style=verbose,`?

Comment: Yes, I want reuse the same footnote number. If I cite twice something, I want that it appears just one time into the footer

Comment: That is much harder. Have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/35673/35864 and linked posts.

Comment: Does the linked question help? If not, can you please explain in more details what you want, what you tried and why the linked post did not help you.