# Several Quotes of the same Source at one Page

Tags: biblatex, footnotes, citing

It looks very ugly if I footcite the same source on the same page.

[image]

My `.bib`-file:

```
@book{hanain,
year={2014},
isbn={978-1493211647},
title={{SAP} {HANA}: An {Introduction}},
publisher={SAP PRESS},
author={Berg, Bjarne and Silvia, Penny},
pages={233--267},
keywords={book}
}
```

I use `biblatex`:

```
    \usepackage[style=authortitle,bibencoding=utf8,sorting=nty,backend=biber]{biblatex}  
    \addbibresource{Bibliography.bib}
```

I footcited this way, what creates the above output:

```
\footcite[Vgl.][27, 36]{hanain}

 \footcite[Vgl.][39]{hanain}
```

Is it possible to quote the same source several times without creating a new line in the footer always?

Comment: You should give a little more information about the citation settings you're using.  A good way to do this would be to produce a minimal (compilable) working example.

Comment: What would you like to see instead, the footnotes refer to different pages in the book, what would the "combined footnote" say? You can use a style such as as `authortitle-ibid` to get "ibid." instead of the full citation.

Comment: Any news here? Currently the question is quite unclear, because you don't state exactly what you would like to see instead of the behaviour you are not too fond of.

Comment: Thank you, moewe. First I thought about the combination in style of " ¹ ... S. 27, 36, 39" and all quotes on that page reference on this (¹) , but I realized that this could be somehow misleading. So I think ibid is a good compromise even though it looks a little bit strange. It seems like ibid is common practice for scenarios like this. I'm just not sure if there is a better solution possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you should collect all the citations of one work because this can lead to massive confusion if you also give page references.

A style like this is not in general impossible though, you will find however that some implementations don't allow for page references at all since they become useless. See for example [biblatex: which style for a footnote once then nothing?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/20637/35864), [Biblatex cite with footnote only once, with use of brackets](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/20787/35864), [Repeat the same reference in footnote on different pages](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/71526/35864), [biblatex repeated citations in footnotes that point back to earlier footnotes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/200286/35864).

You should consider switching to an `-ibid`-type style, for example [`authortitle-ibid`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/examples/61-style-authortitle-ibid.pdf). Then for subsequent citations of the same source you don't get the entire thing again, but only a short "ibid.".