# Multiple \footcite of same literature on same page: How to merge footnotes?

Tags: biblatex, footnotes, multiple-citations

By default, `biblatex` prints a new footnote for every use of `\footcite{...}` regardless of the content.

In case of multiple citations of the same literature on the same page, I'd like to automatically merge the identical `\footcite`s (use the same footnote number for every occurence and print the footnote only once). How an I achieve this?

[image: Explanation]

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{Literature.bib}
\begin{document}
    Some text.\footcite{ExampleBook} Some more text.\footcite{ExampleBook}
\end{document}
```

**Content of Literature.bib**

```
@book{ExampleBook,
    title = {Some Title},
    author = {Some Author},
    year = {1492},
}
```

Comment: What if you decide to give page numbers as well? `\footcite[2]{ExampleBook}` and `\footcite[3]{ExampleBook}` should probably not be merged. It is very unusual to re-use footnotes - even though from time to time people request this.

Comment: @moewe I don' t understand what you mean. From the `biblatex` documentation, the input format is`\footcite[prenote][postnote]{key}`? How would it make sense to enter a page number into the pre- or postnote?

Comment: You can manually repeat a footnote using \footnotemark[\thefootnote] or something to that effect.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Thanks, I didn't know that command. It's not the automatic solution I'm still hoping for, but in case of emergency it'll do just fine.

Comment: There are number of question about this already. Search a bit and see also https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/295413/2388

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Did some more searching now and finally found https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/200286/. It's pretty much exactly what I want, but unfortunately it breaks when changing `style` option of `biblatex` and I have no idea how to fix this.

Comment: The postnote is usually used to give a specific page number in the reference. Ideally you would not cite `sigfridsson`, but also the relevant page, that is done with `\cite[3]{sigfridsson}`.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/200286/35864 is not what you want, it does not give a new number on a new page. You probably want something like https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/35673/35864

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tricky bit is when the `\footcite` is in a paragraph which gets split across two pages.  Both halves think they are on the first page.  The `ifoddpage` package can be used to handle that, but it takes two runs.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{Literature.bib}

\usepackage{xparse}% for multiple optional parameters
\usepackage{ifoddpage}% get correct page number

\makeatletter
\let\oldfootcite=\footcite
\RenewDocumentCommand{\footcite}{O{}O{}m}{\checkoddpage
  \@ifundefined{citepage@#3}{}%
  {\ifnum\csname citepage@#3\endcsname<\oddpage@page\relax
      \global\expandafter\let\csname repeatcite@#3\endcsname=\relax
  \fi}%
  \@ifundefined{repeatcite@#3}%
  {\oldfootcite[#1][#2]{#3}%
    \expandafter\xdef\csname repeatcite@#3\endcsname{\thefootnote}%
    \expandafter\xdef\csname citepage@#3\endcsname{\arabic{page}}}%
  {\footnotemark[\csname repeatcite@#3\endcsname]}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    Some text.\footcite{ExampleBook} Some more text.\footcite{ExampleBook}
    \newpage
    Some more text.\footcite{ExampleBook}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This breaks the optional arguments for pre- and postnote.

Comment: Thanks! As long as every literature is only cited on one page this works great. However when an already-cited literature is cited again on another page, it uses the previous number again and doesn't print a new footnote. So if this code could somehow be modified to reset its behaviour every time a new page starts (?) it would be perfect.

Comment: Okay, I updated the code.

Comment: I get "-NoValue-" fields when omitting the square brackets in the footcite command. Is there a way to not having to write them out when they are empty?

Comment: I must have been in a hurry when I did this.

Comment: @JohnKormylo do you know of a way when you look at it now? It's not really crucial but I'd like to learn how this is done.

Comment: Oops, I fixed it in my version, but curiously not here.Anyway, it is documented in xparse.

Comment: Thank you so much - this was very helpful. Can this solution also be made to consider the pre and postnotes? I have entries with the same page number in the postnote that I'd like to merge into a single footnote.

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea what a prenote or postnote is.