# Citations as footnotes in biblatex

Tags: biblatex, citing, footnotes

I would like to improve the appearance of citations as footnotes. I attach the minimal code, containing an example of what I get and of what I would like to end up with:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,oneside]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[
style=footnote-dw,
backend=bibtex,
autocite=footnote,
singletitle=false,
doi=false,
isbn=false,
url=false,
date=year
]{biblatex}
\DeclareFieldFormat{pages}{\mkfirstpage{#1}}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Article1,
Author = {Alice, A. and Bob, B. and Charlie, C.},
Journal = {Nature},
Month = {01},
Number = {456},
Pages = {1234-1239},
Publisher = {MyPublisher1},
Title = {Title1},
Volume = {123},
Year = {2000}}

@article{Article2,
Author = {Alice, A. and Bob, B. and Charlie, C.},
Journal = {Nature},
Month = {02},
Number = {789},
Pages = {1234-1239},
Publisher = {MyPublisher2},
Title = {Title2},
Volume = {987},
Year = {2000}}
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\noindent What I see is:

I want to cite \cite{Article1}, then both \cite{Article1,Article2}, put footnotes\footnote{This is a footnote}, cite them again\cite{Article1,Article2}.

\vspace{20mm}
\noindent I would like things to appear as:

I want to cite$^{1}$, then both $^{1,2}$, put footnotes$^{3}$, cite them again$^{1,2}$.


\vspace{10mm}
\noindent or as:

I want to cite$^{[1]}$, then both $^{[1,2]}$, put footnotes$^{[3]}$, cite them again$^{[1,2]}$.


\vspace{10mm}
\noindent with in the foot:\\
$[1]$ A. Alice, B. Bob and C. Charlie, "Title1",  Nature 123, 1234 (2000).\\
$[2]$ A. Alice, B. Bob and C. Charlie, "Title2",  Nature 987, 1234 (2000).\\
$[3]$ This is a footnote

\end{document}
```

Do you have any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you please be more specific about what improvements you're looking for?

Comment: @egreg thanks for your interest, maybe it is confusing because my "requests" are in the LaTex/picture attached.

Comment: As I am not yet able to comment I'll have to post an answer: do any of these help? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/71526/repeat-the-same-reference-in-footnote-on-different-pages?rq=1 https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/200286/biblatex-repeated-citations-in-footnotes-that-point-back-to-earlier-footnotes?rq=1 https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20637/biblatex-which-style-for-a-footnote-once-then-nothing https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35673/biblatex-is-there-a-command-analogous-to-ifciteseen-but-within-one-page These seem to cover the issue pretty comprehensively.

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for `\footcite`.

Comment: I think your question was solved in your follow-up https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/413896/35864