# Improvements on citations as footnotes in Biblatex

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, cross-referencing, citing

I'm using the code of https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/275524/154017 , and I would like to ask how to make some changes.

1. Is there a way to modify it in such a way that citations appears as `[1]` instead of `1`?
2. Is there a way of shifting the citations from superscripts `as shown in^1` to in-line `as shown in [1]`?
3. How to deal with footnotes? In the current code they are again indexed numerically starting from `1`, which goes in conflict with citation `1`. Should I use symbols?

Comment: What about https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/20787/35864?

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following solution based on https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/275524/154017 and `bigfoot` footnote handling. You can use `\footnote` for normal footnotes with numbers. `\cite` produces citations with square brackets, also in the footnotes.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{bigfoot}
\DeclareNewFootnote{A}
\usepackage[style=numeric, citetracker=true, pagetracker=true, sorting=none]{biblatex}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\AtEveryCitekey{%
  \ifcsundef{cbx@instcount@curr@\the\c@refsection @\thefield{entrykey}}
    {\csnumgdef{cbx@instcount@curr@\the\c@refsection @\thefield{entrykey}}{0}}
    {}%
  \csnumgdef{cbx@instcount@last@\the\c@refsection @\thefield{entrykey}}{%
    \csuse{cbx@instcount@curr@\the\c@refsection @\thefield{entrykey}}}%
  \csnumgdef{cbx@instcount@curr@\the\c@refsection @\thefield{entrykey}}{\value{instcount}}}

\def\iflastciteonsamepage{%
  \ifsamepage
    {\number\csuse{cbx@instcount@curr@\the\c@refsection @\thefield{entrykey}}}
    {\number\csuse{cbx@instcount@last@\the\c@refsection @\thefield{entrykey}}}}


\DeclareCiteCommand{\cite}[\mkbibbrackets]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cite}%
   \iflastciteonsamepage
     {}
     {\def\@makefnmark{%
        \printtext[labelnumberwidth]{%
          \printfield{labelprefix}%
          \printfield{labelnumber}}%
        \setunit{\addspace}}%
      \footnotetextA{%
        \usedriver
          {\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{default}}
          {\thefield{entrytype}}}}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}
\makeatother

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Title}
\null\vfill\noindent
First citation.\cite{bertram}
First\footnote{Lorem} citation.\cite{companion}
Some recurrent citations on\footnote {ipsum} same page.\cite{bertram,companion,augustine}
\chapter{Title}
\null\vfill\noindent
Recurrent citation on different page.\cite{companion}
Recurrent on different page and first citations.\cite{augustine,cicero}
Recurrent citation on same page.\cite{companion}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]