In Table environment: biblatex repeated citations in footnotes that point back to earlier footnotes
In many situations, it is useful to have citations as footnotes that point back to earlier footnotes.
For instance, here on Page #1, we footnote citations 1 and 2:

And in Page #2, we footnote citation 1 referenced to the previous instance:

For this, I'm defining a new command \myfootcite and adopting the solution proposed here.
When citations are within a table environment, this however no longer works:

MWE:
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[
  left=15mm,
  right=15mm,
  top=15mm,
  bottom=15mm,
  includehead,
  includefoot,
  headsep=0.7em,
  footskip=0.7em,
  headheight=14pt,
  marginparwidth=12mm,
]{geometry}

\usepackage[table,dvipsnames]{xcolor}

\usepackage[style=verbose-inote,backend=biber]{biblatex} 

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    citecolor=black,
    linkcolor=black,
    urlcolor=blue
  }
  
\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[compact]{titlesec}

\usepackage{soul} 
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\setmainfont{Times New Roman}

\counterwithin{table}{section}
\counterwithin{figure}{section}

 %To have 8 pt caption names and texts:
\newcommand\eightpt{\fontsize{8}{10}\selectfont}
\DeclareCaptionFont{eightpt}{\eightpt}
\captionsetup{font=eightpt,skip=0pt}

\hyphenation{in-fra-struc-tu-res}

% To enable footnote citations within tables,
% from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/109471/50467
\usepackage{footnote}
%\usepackage{tablefootnote}
\makesavenoteenv{tabular}
\makesavenoteenv{table}


% To enable biblatex repeated citations in footnotes that point back to earlier footnotes
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/200290/50467
\makeatletter
\DeclareCiteCommand{\myfootcite}
  {}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{myfootcite}}
  {}
  {}

\newbibmacro*{myfootcite}{%
  \ifciteseen
    {\usebibmacro{myfootcite:note}}
    {\mkbibfootnote{\usebibmacro{footcite:full}%
     \usebibmacro{footcite:save}}}}

\newbibmacro*{myfootcite:note}{\footref{cbx@\csuse{cbx@f@\thefield{entrykey}}}}
\makeatother

\DeclareCiteCommand{\myfootcite}   {}   {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%    
\usebibmacro{myfootcite}}   {\mkbibsuperscript{,}}   {}


\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Aloy,
  title={Interrogating protein interaction networks through structural biology},
  author={Aloy, Patrick and Russell, Robert B},
  journal={Proceedings of the National Academy of Sciences},
  volume={99},
  number={9},
  pages={5896--5901},
  year={2002},
  publisher={National Acad Sciences}
}
@article{Folch,
  author={Folch, Jordi and Lees, Mark and Stanley, GH Sloane},
  author+an = {1=highlight},
  journal={Journal of biological chemistry},
  volume={226},
  number={1},
  pages={497--509},
  year={1957},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

Some text here \myfootcite{Aloy} or here.
Also, these report other investigations \myfootcite{Folch}.

\newpage

It is very useful to remember that some studies \myfootcite{Aloy} claimed something interesting.

\newpage


\begin{table}[h!]
\begin{tabular}{|>{\centering}m{0.04\linewidth}|>{\hspace{0pt}}m{0.404\linewidth}|>{\hspace{0pt}}m{0.471\linewidth}|>{\hspace{0pt}}m{0.027\linewidth}} 
\cline{1-3}
\textbf{One} & \multicolumn{1}{>{\centering\hspace{0pt}}m{0.404\linewidth}|}{\textbf{Study 1}} & \multicolumn{1}{>{\centering\hspace{0pt}}m{0.471\linewidth}|}{\textbf{Study 2}}  \\
\cline{1-3}
 \textbf{A} & 
Working with \myfootcite{Folch} 
  & 
    Other studies \myfootcite{Aloy}
  \\
 \hline
\textbf{B} & 
Those same studies\myfootcite{Aloy}
& 
 The integration  \\
   \hline
\end{tabular}
\captionof{table}{Caption table}
\label{table:2_transfer}
\end{table}

\end{document}




The solution in biblatex repeated citations in footnotes that point back to earlier footnotes relies on citation tracking, which is disabled in floats like tables by default, because they are considered to be "outside the text". You can pass the option trackfloats to biblatex to have citation tracking not disabled in floats.
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[table,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=verbose-inote,trackfloats]{biblatex}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    citecolor=black,
    linkcolor=black,
    urlcolor=blue
}

\counterwithin{table}{section}
\counterwithin{figure}{section}

% To enable footnote citations within tables,
% from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/109471/50467
\usepackage{footnote}
%\usepackage{tablefootnote}
\makesavenoteenv{tabular}
\makesavenoteenv{table}

% To enable biblatex repeated citations in footnotes that point back to earlier footnotes
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/200290/50467
\makeatletter
\DeclareCiteCommand{\myfootcite}
  {}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{myfootcite}}
  {}
  {}

\newbibmacro*{myfootcite}{%
  \ifciteseen
    {\usebibmacro{myfootcite:note}}
    {\mkbibfootnote{\usebibmacro{footcite:full}%
     \usebibmacro{footcite:save}}}}

\newbibmacro*{myfootcite:note}{\footref{cbx@\csuse{cbx@f@\thefield{entrykey}}}}
\makeatother

\DeclareCiteCommand{\myfootcite}[\unskip]
  {}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{myfootcite}}
  {\mkbibsuperscript{,}}
  {}


\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Aloy,
  title={Interrogating protein interaction networks through structural biology},
  author={Aloy, Patrick and Russell, Robert B},
  journal={Proceedings of the National Academy of Sciences},
  volume={99},
  number={9},
  pages={5896--5901},
  year={2002},
  publisher={National Acad Sciences}
}
@article{Folch,
  author={Folch, Jordi and Lees, Mark and Stanley, GH Sloane},
  author+an = {1=highlight},
  journal={Journal of biological chemistry},
  volume={226},
  number={1},
  pages={497--509},
  year={1957},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
Some text here \myfootcite{Aloy} or here.
Also, these report other investigations \myfootcite{Folch}.

\newpage

It is very useful to remember that some studies \myfootcite{Aloy} claimed something interesting.

\newpage


\begin{table}[h!]
\begin{tabular}{|>{\centering}m{0.04\linewidth}|>{\hspace{0pt}}m{0.404\linewidth}|>{\hspace{0pt}}m{0.471\linewidth}|>{\hspace{0pt}}m{0.027\linewidth}}
\cline{1-3}
\textbf{One} & \multicolumn{1}{>{\centering\hspace{0pt}}m{0.404\linewidth}|}{\textbf{Study 1}} & \multicolumn{1}{>{\centering\hspace{0pt}}m{0.471\linewidth}|}{\textbf{Study 2}}  \\
\cline{1-3}
 \textbf{A} &
Working with \myfootcite{Folch}
  &
    Other studies \myfootcite{Aloy}
  \\
 \hline
\textbf{B} &
Those same studies\myfootcite{Aloy}
&
 The integration  \\
   \hline
\end{tabular}
\captionof{table}{Caption table}
\label{table:2_transfer}
\end{table}

\end{document}



Many thanks for the explanation! It worked
