# citereset=chapter does not work for me

Tags: biblatex

As I understood this option, when I have something like
\footcite{test}, ..., \footcite{test}, it should have the same footline and it should not make the footline twice, right? It is not working for me!

Comment: The behaviour of the citetracker greatly depends on the style you use, so without a MWE a diagnosis is not really possible. From what you write though I seem to gather that you want footnote numbers to be "re-used" such that one citation always refers to the same footnote number. This is non-standard, but has been implemented on this site [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/20637/35864), [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/20787/35864) or [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/71526/35864). But then I might have misunderstood what you want, maybe you could be a little bit more precise.

Comment: Can you make your question more precise, please. As it stands now I have absolutely no idea what you are asking for. Did any of the links do what you want? Do you even want something like that?

Comment: Moewe, I am still working with solutions you presented above. Since they are not that easy to implement I will rephrase my question in case it is not working. Anyway thank you for the hints.

Comment: In that case I would prefer to close this question here as a duplicate of [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/71526/35864) linked to above and encourage you to ask a new question with [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864) if need be.

Comment: that is for sure the best solution, let us close this question.