# How to make footcite refer to the first footnote when citing identical references?

Tags: biblatex

I am writing a document where I am forced to insert citations of relevant bibliography as footnotes. I am using a similar text for comparison, and I noticed that the bibliography style is rather compact:

```
As it is shown in [1], $2=1$; compare also [2] for a more
combinatorial proof of this result. 

[...] 

Remember that the main theorem in [1,2] entail that $2=1$; [3] 
aims to apply this result to a statement equivalent to RH (see [4]).

=========
[1]: N. True; "A simple proof of something false" (1989). 
[2]: A. Las; "A difficult proof of something false" (2001).
[3]: T. Kyle; "You could have proved something better than this" (2002).
```

When referring again to [1], only a superscript with the corresponding footnote where it has been cited the first time is printed. I think this is done with clever cross-referencing and a bit of biblatex magic, but my bib-fu is rather poor, so I'm not able to backward-engineer the pdf to understand how this is done.

I tried by simply juggling with `style`s in `biblatex` options, to no avail.

---

**Edit**: I produced a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents,lipsum}
\usepackage[style=verbose-ibid,backend=bibtex]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{ntrue,
  title={A simple proof of something false},
  author={N. True},
  journal={Journal of Pure and Applied Algebra},
  volume={9},
  number={2},
  pages={207--220}
}

@article{alas,
    AUTHOR = {A. Las},
     TITLE = {A difficult proof of something false},
   JOURNAL = {J. Homotopy Relat. Struct.},
    VOLUME = {2},
      YEAR = {2007},
    NUMBER = {2},
     PAGES = {295--314},
   MRCLASS = {18E40 (18D30)},
  MRNUMBER = {2369170 (2008m:18023)}
}

@article{tkyle,
    AUTHOR = {T. Kyle},
     TITLE = {You could have proved something better than this},
   JOURNAL = {Trans. Amer. Math. Soc.},
  FJOURNAL = {Transactions of the American Mathematical Society},
    VOLUME = {353},
      YEAR = {2001}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
As it is shown in [\footcite{ntrue}], $$2=1.$$ compare also [\footcite{alas}] for a more
combinatorial proof of this result. 

\lipsum[3]

Remember that the main theorem in [\footcite{ntrue}, \footcite{alas}] entail that $2=1$; [\footcite{tkyle}] aims to apply this result to a statement equivalent to RH.
\end{document}
```

I want that the second reference `\footcite{ntrue}` points to footnote 1. Obviously (if possible) without defining a command which refers to a footnote (this forces me to keep track of each occurrence of each key, and note manually who's the first: it can be done, but...)

Comment: Have you asked the document author how it is done?

Comment: I could. But there are reasons *cough* for which it is better not to do it.

Comment: If it is for a journal submission or particular publisher, they may provide a suitable class or package designed to comply with the guidelines. But if you want help here, you can encourage people by providing a Minimum Working Example which people can play with.

Comment: Please have a look at [biblatex : which style for a footnote once then nothing?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/20637/35864), [Biblatex cite with footnote only once, with use of brackets](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/20787/35864) and [Repeat the same reference in footnote on different pages](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/71526/35864). Depending on whether (and if so, how) you want to interact with normal footnotes, a solution might be easier or more complicated.

Comment: I wonder if the Oscola biblatex package might be doing this? It's the UK's standard legal Citation style, with the first footnote being `Smith, Law Book, 2009, Oxford` and the subsequent footnote has it `Smith (n.1)`

Comment: @tetrapharmakon [This answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/71566/82186) addresses the essence of the problem. You can work from there, depending on your styling choices.

Comment: Did any of the links help you? As it stands now, I'm very much inclined to think your question is a duplicate of [Repeat the same reference in footnote on different pages](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/71526/35864).

Comment: This is not a duplicate of that thread, I don't want that the reference be repeated on the second page. I only want a pointer to the first citation, each time I recast it, and anything else