# Remove title from all citations in beamer

Tags: beamer, biblatex, biber

I am citing multiple papers in my presentation, and sometimes I repeat the citations on multiple slides. Using the settings

```
\usepackage[
backend=biber,
bibstyle=numeric,
style=verbose-ibid,
maxnames=2, minnames=1,
sorting=none,
natbib=true,
url=false, 
doi=false,
isbn=false,
eprint=false]{biblatex}
```

I can suppress the title for the first time I cite an article (using `autocite{}`), but for every citation later in the presentation it includes it again, while neglecting the journal title (which I would like to have instead). How can I use the journal every time when I cite the paper, instead of the name?

MWE:
`presentation.tex`-file:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{beamer}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[
backend=biber,
bibstyle=numeric,
style=verbose-ibid,
maxnames=2, minnames=1,
%sortlocale=nn_NO,
sorting=none,
natbib=true,
url=false, 
doi=false,
isbn=false,
eprint=false]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}
\AtEveryBibitem{\clearfield{title}}
\AtEveryCitekey{\clearfield{title}}
\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        This is the first slide, citing \autocite{Schmitt2010} and \autocite{Wenmaekers2017}.

        Furthermore, I want to cite \autocite{Wenmaekers2017} again on this slide
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
Aaand let's cite \autocite{Schmitt2010} and \autocite{Wenmaekers2017} again on the second slide
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

and `bibliography.bib`:

```
@article{Schmitt2010,
    abstract = {Back protectors for snowboarders were analysed with respect to their potential to prevent spinal injury.},
    author = {Schmitt, Kai-Uwe and Liechti, Bendicht and Michel, Frank I and St{\"{a}}mpfli, Rolf and Br{\"{u}}hwiler, Paul A},
    doi = {10.1136/bjsm.2010.072728},
    isbn = {1473-0480},
    issn = {0306-3674},
    journal = {Br. J. Sports Med.},     
    number = {11},
    pages = {822--826},
    pmid = {20647300},
    title = {{Are current back protectors suitable to prevent spinal injury in recreational snowboarders?}},
    volume = {44},
    year = {2010}
}
@article{Wenmaekers2017,
    abstract = {Symphony orchestra musicians are exposed to noise levels that put them at risk of developing hear-ing damage. This study evaluates the potential effectivity of common control measures used in orchestras on open stages with a typical symphonic setup. A validated acoustic prediction model is used that calculates binaural sound exposure levels at the ears of all musicians in the orchestra. The model calculates the equivalent sound levels for a performance of the first 2 min of the 4th move-ment of Mahler's 1st symphony, which can be considered representative for loud orchestral music. Calculated results indicate that risers, available space, and screens at typical positions do not signif-icantly influence sound exposure. A hypothetical scenario with surround screens shows that, even when shielding all direct sound from others, sound exposure is reduced moderately with the largest effect on players in loud sections. In contrast, a dramatic change in room acoustic conditions only leads to considerable reductions for soft players. It can be concluded that significant reductions are only reached with extreme measures that are unrealistic. It seems impossible for the studied physi-cal measures to be effective enough to replace hearing protection devices such as ear plugs.},
    author = {Wenmaekers, Remy and Nicolai, Bareld and Hornikx, Maarten and Kohlrausch, Armin},
    doi = {10.1121/1.5002684//doi.org/10.1121/1.5012689},
    journal = {J. Acoust. Soc. Am.},
    number = {10},
    title = {{Why orchestral musicians are bound to wear earplugs: About the ineffectiveness of physical measures to reduce sound exposure}},
    url = {https://doi.org/10.1121/1.5012689{\%}0Ahttps://doi.org/10.1121/1.5012689},
    volume = {1421},
    year = {2017}
}
```

The citations on the second slide contain the title of the paper, instead of the title of the journal, as it is on the first slide. I would like to get the same pattern on the second slide as I have it on the first slide

Comment: Can you turn your code snippet into an actual [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864), please? I fail to see from the code you have shown so far how it would suppress the title in the first citation. It would also help if you could describe in more detail what you would like to see. Would you like to suppress titles of `@book`s as well?

Comment: @moewe: I created an MWE. If it is possible not to suppress titles from ` @book` and `@phdthesis`, while suppressing the title of papers, how can I do that?

Comment: In your MWE the title is also shown on the first slide. Just so I get you right. You want to suppress the title everywhere and you want the same output on all slides?

Comment: @moewe: Fixed, forgot two commands. Now the titles are not shown at the first occurence, but on every following occurence

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you want the exact same citations on all slides, I would go for `\footfullcite` instead of `verbose-ibid`'s citations. Luckily you use `\autocite`, so the necessary changes are quite minute.

If you want to suppress article titles, you may want to look at one of the styles of the `biblatex-chem` bundle. They offer the option `articletitle`. The MWE below uses `chem-rsc`, but you could also try `chem-acs` or `chem-angew`.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[
backend=biber,
style=chem-rsc,
maxnames=2, minnames=1,
sorting=none,
natbib=true]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\DeclareAutoCiteCommand{footfull}{\footfullcite}{\footfullcites}
\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{autocite=footfull}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  This is the first slide, citing \autocite{sigfridsson} and \autocite{geer}.

  Furthermore, I want to cite \autocite{geer} again on this slide
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
  Aaand let's cite \autocite{sigfridsson} and \autocite{geer} again on the second slide
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is it also possible to combine two citations into one, if it occurs multiple times on the same page?

Comment: @arc_lupus Have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/20637/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/35673/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/20787/35864 and linked questions. Maybe you can find your answer there. If not, please ask a new question detailing what you have tried so far and how it did not work for you along with a detailed description of what you expect.