# Footnote citation in authoryear style but bibliography numbered

Tags: bibliographies, citing

I would like to know if it is possible to have the footnote citations in the form of number and  authoryear, like `[1] Einstein, A. 1905` but still have the sources in my bibliography numbered.

Thanks !

EDIT: Trying MWE, specifying what i want.

```
\documentclass{srcreprt}

\usepackage[style=numeric,citestyle=authoryear]{biblatex}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithout{footnote}{chapter}

\bibliography{Literature}

\begin{document}

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Now I would also like to display the number of the source in my footnote, like

```
[1] Einstein, A. 1905
```

Comment: That crucially depends on the bibliography package (`natbib`, `cite`, `jurabib`, `biblatex`, ...) you plan to use and the specific style you want to start from. A [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864)/[MWEB](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864) of what you have so far would help us understand that and get started more quickly. For now, please keep in mind that the footnote numbers and the numbering in the bibliography will probably not coincide, rendering the numbers in the bibliography useless.

Comment: Edited my Post for clarity, thanks for your help!

Comment: Do you want the same number to be used if you cite the same source again? That is somewhat unusual in published works (only papers in chemistry do something similar), but apparently some people are really keen on that. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/20637/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/35673/35864

Comment: I actually made it  how I want it, but thanks for your help !

Comment: Then please add an answer bellow yourself so other people can benefit from it.