# How to have a footnote with author name and year

Tags: bibliographies, citing

I actually want to get the author name and year in the footnote, I'm using overleaf with pdftex
I have this library file :

```latex
@misc{cite1,
    author = "Orti, E. and Bredas, J.L. and Clarisse, C.",
    title = {Something},
    year = 2008,
}

@misc{cite2,
    author = "George, A. and Carlin, B.",
    title = {Something else},
    year = 2016,
}
```

Now in my file, I do add a refernce to the library item:

```latex
In this study \footnote{\cite{cite2}}, we can clearly see that....
```

However, it does only create this footnote: [2] without showing the author name and the year.
Instead what I need in the footnote is : "George, A. et Al. 2016"  not [2]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest setup for author-year citations in footnotes is probably using `biblatex`.

With `style=authoryear,` you select an author-year style. With `autocite=footnote,` you get footnote citations from `\autocite`.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=authoryear, autocite=footnote, backend=biber]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\null\vfill % only for this example!

Lorem ipum \autocite[380-382]{sigfridsson}
dolor \autocite{worman}
sit \autocite[12-45]{nussbaum}
amet \autocite[8]{geer}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Sigfridsson and Ryde 1998, pp. 380–382.]

On a local system you'd have to configure your editor to use Biber ([Biblatex with Biber: Configuring my editor to avoid undefined citations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864)) and run a complete cycle LaTeX, Biber, LaTeX, LaTeX to ensure all citations resolve correctly (see [Question mark or bold citation key instead of citation number](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/35864) for background). But on Overleaf it is enough to just clear the cache (https://de.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/Clearing_the_cache; if that is necessary at all), the system (more precisely the amazing `latexmk`) will run all required programs for you.

There are many customisation options for `biblatex`. [Guidelines for customizing biblatex styles](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12806/35864) is a good start for first steps, but there is a lot more.

You can find some more details about `biblatex` at [bibtex vs. biber and biblatex vs. natbib](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25701/35864), [What to do to switch to biblatex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5091/35864) and [biblatex in a nutshell (for beginners)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13509/35864).

Comment: Thanks, thats working properly.
If I have 1 reference that I need to site 2 times, pls what can I use?

Comment: @roger You can just cite it again `Lorem \autocite[380-382]{sigfridsson} ipsum \autocite[380-382]{sigfridsson}`.

Comment: thanks @moewe,  however If I did this, I get multiple references, Instead I need to use only one refernce to get only one footnote for the same citation

Comment: @roger Suppose you cite `sigfridsson` on page 4 and again on page 28. Should your reader have to run through all footnotes again just to find the footnote matching the citation number? If you want citations in footnotes I think the most sensible way is to have each citation is a footnote of its own. If you want a numeric citation style with full first citations, *much* more work is needed. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/20637/35864.

Comment: thanks very much. the link you shared was exactly what I need