# Don't reset citations counter in book document class when using footcite

Tags: biblatex, citing, biber, bibliographystyle, footcite

I am working on my Master's thesis and the citations are required to appear in the footnotes of the page where they are cited so I am using `\footcite` whenever I need to reference something in my bibliography.

However,, by default, this means that after every chapter, the citations counter is reset such that the citations of each chapter start back at 1. However, the citations at the end of the bibliography don't! For example, the first citation of the 5th chapter appears as 1 in the footnote, but it is actually the 20th citation of the whole document. How can I make the footnote to show that it is refencing 20?

This is how I am using the bibatex package:

```
\usepackage[citestyle=verbose,bibstyle=numeric,sorting=none,defernumbers,backend=biber]{biblatex}
```

Comment: Note that it is never guaranteed that the footnote number coincides with the numeric citation label listed in the bibliography when you just use `\footcite`. Just try what happens if you cite the same source multiple times. You'd need a much more complex approach like https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/20637/35864 or https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/35673/35864, which all have their drawbacks.