# Adding compressed number feature to verbose-ibid

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, formatting, declarecitecommand

I am using verbose-ibid for my citations and want the citations to:

1. be seen as compressed footnotes in the text (e.g. 1-3 instead of 1,2,3)
2. appear as abbreviated citations in the sidebar

I have the normal verbose-ibid working such that the citations appear in the sidebar, but I am having a hard time figuring out how to compress the footnotes in-text. I've tried:

1. adding in the sortcites command from numeric-comp
2. looking at combining functionalities of the numeric-comp package but don't know what parts to copy out, or how to create a file that will be called instead of the normal package file (I am working in Overleaf, so don't have any package files downloaded)
3. writing my own \DeclareCiteCommand (but I don't even know where to start on this)

I'd really appreciate some direction on this! Thanks.

Comment: `verbose-ibid` just produces citations in footnotes. This means that the numbers you are seeing generated by `\cite` and friends are footnote numbers and are not guaranteed to have any connection to any other numbering that might be produced. In particular if you cite the same source multiple times (no matter if on the same page or different pages), it will create a new footnote each time with a new number.

Comment: Have you ever seen the style you are looking for in a paper or book? It is fairly unusual AFAICT. But there are `biblatex` implementation of something similar. You may want to have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/20637/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/35673/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/71526/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/20787/35864 and linked questions.